# how to copy a list to a new list, or retrieve list by value in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, list

I noticed in c# there is a method for Lists:
CopyTo -> that copies to arrays, is there a nicer way to copy to a new list? problem is, I want to retrieve the list by value to be able to remove items before displaying them, i dont want the original list to be modified, that too doesnt seem to be easily attainable, any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
List<MyType> copy = new List<MyType>(original);
```

Comment: Modifying an element in the list (not adding or removing) still impacts both lists...

Comment: As @Zoop said, it is not working. When inside list something is changed, it is also changed it in the original.

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 5):

> I want to retrieve the list by value to be able to remove items before displaying them,

```
var newlist = oldList.Where(<specify condition here>).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 3.5, the resulting array can have ToList() called on it.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new `List` and use the appropriate constructor:

```
IList<Obj> newList = new List<Obj>(oldList);
```

Comment: Modifying an element in the list (not adding or removing) still impacts both lists...

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work.  Passing a list to the constructor of a new list.

```
    List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>(list1);
```

Comment: Modifying an element in the list (not adding or removing) still impacts both lists...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cloning (Clone()) each item and adding the clone to a new collection?

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you have a list of references, the list

```
List<Object> list2 = new List<Object>(list1);
```

does not work.

This should solve your problem:

[How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: the question is about copying, not cloning