# How do I copy items from list to list without foreach?

Tags: c#, oop, list, foreach, copy

How do I transfer the items contained in one `List` to another in C# without using `foreach`?

Comment: If you need a deep clone of the original list you will find the answer in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c

Answer (score 667, accepted):

You could try this:

```
List<Int32> copy = new List<Int32>(original);
```

or if you're using C# 3 and .NET 3.5, with Linq, you can do this:

```
List<Int32> copy = original.ToList();
```

---

I see that this answer is still getting upvotes. Well, here's a secret for ya: *the above answer is still using a foreach*. Please don't upvote this any further.

Comment: If the items are of type `MyClass` instead of `Integer`, does it copy the items too, or just reference them?

Comment: Not working with Non-primitive types.  List<StudentClass> copy = new List<StudentClass>(lstStudentClass);

Comment: It works with all types, as long as `lstStudentClass` is an `IEnumerable<StudentClass>`, it will work. If you experience otherwise you need to provide more information.

Comment: what is the meaning of (original); at the end

Comment: You pass on a collection to the constructor of the list, and the constructor will then copy all the elements of that collection into the newly created list.

Comment: @PedroMoreira For complex object you can do: `origninal.Select(o => new Complex(o)).ToList()` to get a list of new objects, not copied references

Comment: @JohnStock: Nothing's being replaced here - it's not changing any existing list. It's just creating a *new* list with the items. What do you believe is being replaced?

Answer (score 210):

To add the contents of one list to another list which already exists, you can use:

```
targetList.AddRange(sourceList);
```

If you're just wanting to create a new copy of the list, see the top answer.

Comment: @mrmillsy: Well they do different things. My answer is focused on "I already have a list, and I want to copy things to it"

Comment: True.  My question would probably be better suited to a new question anyway.  Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: If you wanted to replace the contents of an existing list completely, you would call targetList.Clear() first.

Comment: This is the correct answer as copying implies adding, not replacing.
The OP asked for copying ITEMS not the entire collection.

Answer (score 45):

For a list of elements

```
List<string> lstTest = new List<string>();

lstTest.Add("test1");
lstTest.Add("test2");
lstTest.Add("test3");
lstTest.Add("test4");
lstTest.Add("test5");
lstTest.Add("test6");
```

If you want to copy all the elements

```
List<string> lstNew = new List<string>();
lstNew.AddRange(lstTest);
```

If you want to copy the first 3 elements

```
List<string> lstNew = lstTest.GetRange(0, 3);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `AddRange` does not specify it in the docs, that it copies or just adds objects by reference, but if you search the implementation, it uses `Array.Copy` (static) to copy the data.

Answer (score 7):

And this is if copying a single property to another list is needed:

```
targetList.AddRange(sourceList.Select(i => i.NeededProperty));
```

Answer (score 4):

This method will create a copy of your list  but your  type should be serializable.

**Use:**

```
List<Student> lstStudent = db.Students.Where(s => s.DOB < DateTime.Now).ToList().CopyList();
```

**Method:**

```
public static List<T> CopyList<T>(this List<T> lst)
    {
        List<T> lstCopy = new List<T>();
        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(stream, item);
                stream.Position = 0;
                lstCopy.Add((T)formatter.Deserialize(stream));
            }
        }
        return lstCopy;
    }
```

Comment: Does the serialization create a significant performance penalty?

Answer (score 4):

**Easy to map different set of list by linq without for loop**

```
var List1= new List<Entities1>();

var List2= new List<Entities2>();

var List2 = List1.Select(p => new Entities2
        {
            EntityCode = p.EntityCode,
            EntityId = p.EntityId,
            EntityName = p.EntityName
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the top answers, if you want copies of "the objects in the list", then you can use `Select` and make the copies. (While the other answers make "a copy of a list", this answer makes "a list of copies").

Suppose your item has a `Copy` method:

```
List<MyObject> newList = oldList.Select(item => item.Copy()).ToList();
```

Or that you can create a new object from the previous one with a constructor:

```
List<MyObject> newList = oldList.Select(item => new MyObject(item)).ToList();
```

The result of `Select` is an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` that you can also pass to `AddRange` for instance, if your goal is to add to an existing list.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<string> GetClone(this List<string> source)
{
    return source.Select(item => (string)item.Clone()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Code only answer tend to be considered low quality.  Can you add an explanation as to how your answer solves the issue, and how this differs from existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

OK this is working well
From the suggestions above GetRange( ) does not work for me with a list as an argument...so sweetening things up a bit from posts above: ( thanks everyone :)

```
/*  Where __strBuf is a string list used as a dumping ground for data  */
public List < string > pullStrLst( )
{
    List < string > lst;

    lst = __strBuf.GetRange( 0, __strBuf.Count );     

    __strBuf.Clear( );

    return( lst );
}
```

Comment: This is not even an answer.

Comment: mmm...ok well some of the suggestions above simply don't work in Vis 17
I have cleaned up the best answer provided...and hey presto...it works  :)

Answer (score -9):

Here another method but it is little worse compare to other.

```
List<int> i=original.Take(original.count).ToList();
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Why not `ToList()` directly?

Comment: Well I think, If I wanted to copy only the first 10 elements from one list to another, this would make sense.
List<int> i=original.Take(10).ToList();