# Change object type of a existing collection (OptionMetadataCollection) and mapping of existing types

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011

Final solution:

```
public class CustomOptionMetadata : OptionMetadata
{
    public CustomOptionMetadata(OptionMetadata optionMetadata) : base() 
    {
        this.Description = optionMetadata.Description;
        this.ExtensionData = optionMetadata.ExtensionData;
        this.Managed = optionMetadata.IsManaged;
        this.Label = optionMetadata.Label;
        this.MetadataId = optionMetadata.MetadataId;
        this.Value = optionMetadata.Value;
    }

    public string MappedName { get; set; }
    public bool? Managed { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
foreach (MappingEntity meAtt in mappingEntityList.FindAll(me => me.ParentID == meEnt.ID))
{
    CRMOrganizationEntityAttribute crmOrganizationEntityAttribute = new CRMOrganizationEntityAttribute(meAtt.ID, meAtt.Name, true);
    if (meAtt.IsPicklist)
    {
        List<OptionMetadata> optionMetadataList = GetAttributePickList(meEnt.Name, meAtt.Name);
        if (optionMetadataList.Count > 0)
        {
            crmOrganizationEntityAttribute.OptionMetadataColl = optionMetadataList.Select<OptionMetadata, CustomOptionMetadata>(metadata => new CustomOptionMetadata(metadata)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    CRMOrgEnt.CRMAttributeNameList.Add(crmOrganizationEntityAttribute);
}
```

============================================================================

I am currently working on a mapping application, which already has a lot of custom objects. In an attempt to limit the lookups and definition of the classes, I thought about extending the already existing classes which I need anyways.

The `OptionMetaDataCollection` is part of the Microsoft.Xrm.SDK.Metadata library and has the `OptionMetaData` object in its Ilist.

Now I would like to create something like this:

```
public partial class CustomOptionMetadataCollection : OptionMetadataCollection
{
    public CustomOptionMetadataCollection() : base() { }
}

public partial class CustomOptionMetadata : OptionMetadata
{
    public CustomOptionMetadata() : base() { }

    public string MappedName { get; set; }
}
```

But how would I change the `Ilist<OptionMetaData>` which is currently in the `OptionMetadatacollection` to my `IList<CustomOptionMetaData>`. I am aware that I can make my own Ilist of the `CustomOptionMetaDataCollection`, however I would (with my mind on the rest of the code) list to use something simulair with more advanced collection classes.

I am also wondering how I would than map the `OptionMetaDataCollection` object to my `CustomOptionMetadataCollection`. I can create a loop but I am looking for a more effecient way to do the mapping.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is your question how do you initialize the custom classes from the Microsoft defined ones?  Also, I'm not understanding what benefit you're getting from the custom classes...

Comment: Please see below in the comment of the answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would use a Where, not FindAll.  A find all will create a new list, copying all the values, the Where will just enumerate over your current list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert an `IList<OptionMetadata>` to a `IList<CustomOptionMetadata>`, you're effectively asking; How can I convert my base class (`OptionMetadata`) to a derived class (`CustomOptionMetadata`)?

Let's take the `IList` out of the equation for the moment - after all its just holding multiple copies of the class.

At it simplest level you basically want to do:

```
OptionMetadata optionMetadata = new OptionMetadata();
CustomOptionMetadata customOptionMetadata = (CustomOptionMetadata)optionMetadata;
```

Unfortunately this type of downcasting isnt really something C# does.

As Adam Wright describes in [A way of casting a base type to a derived type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124336/a-way-of-casting-a-base-type-to-a-derived-type).

> This is downcasting, and there is no sane down way to handle it, . . .  (subclasses provide more than base
>   classes - where does this "more" come from?)

So that said there are other ways to handle this, for example adding a constructor to your custom class which takes the base class.

```
class OptionMetadata
{
    public int X;
}

class CustomOptionMetadata : OptionMetadata
{
    public int Y;

    public CustomOptionMetadata(OptionMetadata metadata)
    {
        this.Y = metadata.X * 2;
    }
}
```

Then at its simplest it becomes:

```
OptionMetadata optionMetadata = new OptionMetadata();
CustomOptionMetadata customOptionMetadata = new CustomOptionMetadata(optionMetadata);
```

And to put the `IList` back into context.

```
IList<OptionMetadata> optionMetadata = new List<OptionMetadata>() 
{            
    new OptionMetadata(),
    new OptionMetadata()
};

IList<CustomOptionMetadata> customOptionMetadata = optionMetadata
    .Select<OptionMetadata, CustomOptionMetadata>(metadata => new CustomOptionMetadata(metadata)).ToList();
```

I'm not really sure what you mean by 'mapping' one collection to another, but its sounds a bit like the same problem where you are trying to downcast a base class to a derived class. It not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve (what is the derived class actually doing?). If you just want to copy the contents of one collection to another I would suggest having a look at [How do I copy items from list to list without foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952185/how-do-i-copy-items-from-list-to-list-without-foreach).

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I needed to know exactly what you answered. I was wondering if this type of downcasting worth be supported. I also wondered if the collection is more than just an Ilist and therefor If I can / should replace the object within that Ilist of the collection definition. But your answer is clear, I will create a Ilist.

Also:  .Select<OptionMetadata, CustomOptionMetadata>(metadata => new CustomOptionMetadata(metadata)).ToList(); is what I meant with mapping. I do not want to loop one list to fill the other and this is exactly how I want to resolve this. Thank you very much

Comment: @Hendricks you do realize that underneath the covers, the select is just dong a loop?

Comment: @Daryl, Yes I do but I am trying to learn some while doing the development and I knew there is a "more clean" way for doing this than writing your own foreach loop. So this was part of what I was looking for. Thank you Daryl. Any other tips or points on for example my final solution are always much appreciated.