# How to keep values from a List<T> in a model after clearing the list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a List that receives ids. It is instantiated outside the foreach statement.

```
List<int> indices = new List<int>();

foreach (var m in docsRelacionadosModel)
{
   //.. do stuff
   modelTemp.indices = indices;

   //..here I do more stuff and some time it goes to the next iteration and I need to keep the value in indices to get more values.

    //although in a condition

    if(isOk) {
        //I save the value of this list to a model
        model.indices = modelTemp.indices;

        //And I need to clear the list to get new values
        indices.Clear();  <--- This will clear the values saved in model.indices
    }
}
```

As it has values passed by reference, how can I keep the values in model.indices?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a copy of the list and save that *copy* to `model.indecies`.  While there are a number of ways of copying the list the LINQ `ToList` extension method is probably the most convenient:

```
model.indices = modelTemp.indices.ToList();
```

Another option is to just use the `List` constructor:

```
model.indices = new List<int>(modelTemp.indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a copy of the list:

```
model.indices = new List<int>(modelTemp.indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952185/how-do-i-copy-items-from-list-to-list-without-foreach,), the easiest way may be to call ToList on your list:

```
model.indices = modelTemp.indices.ToList();
```

You could also instantiate as a new list, passing your list as a constructor parameter.