# Generic Lists copying references rather than creating a copiedList

Tags: vb.net, generics, reference

I was developing a small function when trying to run an enumerator across a list and then carry out some action. (Below is an idea of what I was trying to do.

When trying to remove I got a "Collection cannot be modified"  which after I had actually woken up I realised that tempList must have just been assigned myLists reference rather than a copy of myLists. After that I tried to find a way to say

tempList = myList.copy

However nothing seems to exist?? I ended up writing a small for loop that then just added each item from myLsit into tempList but I would have thought there would have been another mechanism (like clone??)

So my question(s):

- is my assumption about tempList receiving a reference to myList correct
- How should a list be copied to another list?

  ```
      private myList as List (Of something)

  sub new()
      myList.add(new Something)
  end sub

  sub myCalledFunction()
      dim tempList as new List (Of Something)
      tempList = myList
      Using i as IEnumerator = myList.getEnumarator
         while i.moveNext
             'if some critria is met then 
             tempList.remove(i.current)
         end
      end using

  end sub
  ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By writing `tempList = myList` you don't make a copy oh the collection, you only make tempList reference myList. Try this instead : `dim tempList as new List (Of Something)(myList)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this - use LINQ to create a new list from the original, for example:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim nums As New List(Of Integer)

        nums.Add(1)
        nums.Add(2)
        nums.Add(3)
        nums.Add(4)

        Dim k = (From i In nums _
                 Select i).ToList()

    For Each number As Integer In nums
        k.Remove(number)
    Next
    End Sub
```

`k` will then be a new list of numbers which are not linked to the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you called myCalledFunction(byVal aListCopy as Something) you can let the framework do the work.

Answer (score 0):

If your list consists of value types you can just create a new list with the old list passed in the constructor. If you are going to be doing a deep copy of a reference object your best bet is to have your reference type implement `ICloneable` ([example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0160__Collections/ICloneable.htm)). You can then loop through and clone each object or you could add an extension method (like this c# [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)).