# Clone a list of reference types that CANNOT implement ICloneable

Tags: .net, list, collections, clone

Is there an easier/tidier way to deep clone a list of reference types that do not implement ICloneable.

Currently have been looping through each object in the list like so:

```
    Dim myListCopy As New List(Of ListObj)
    For Each lo As ListObj In MyList
        myListCopy.Add(lo.ShallowCopy)
    Next
```

The object ListObj contains only value types and returns a shallow memberwise.

This works however I cam across this post here: [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

I don't really understand whats going on in the Extension, is it possible to the shollowCopy function to an extension and avoid iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write an extension method, it will still have to iterate over your list in some way or other.  For VB.net, the extension method will look something like...

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function Clone(MyList as List(Of ListObj)) as List(Of ListObj)
    Dim myListCopy As New List(Of ListObj) 
    For Each lo As ListObj In MyList 
        myListCopy.Add(lo.ShallowCopy) 
    Next 
    Clone = myListCopy
End Function
```

Then when you need to shallow copy your list of ListObj items, you would...

```
Dim aList As New List(Of ListObj)
''' add stuff here
Dim anotherList As List(Of ListObj)
anotherList = aList.Clone()
```

Comment: Thanks very much that was just what I was looking for! Was getting bogged down in all that LINQ'esque programming that I know nothing about.