# Undo changes in entity framework entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, rollback

this might be a trivial question but: Since ADO.NET entity framework automatically tracks changes (in generated entities) and therefore keeps the original values, how can I rollback changes made to the entity objects?

I have a form which allows the user to edit a set of "Customer" entities in a grid view.

Now I have two buttons "Accept" and "Revert": if "Accept" is clicked, I call `Context.SaveChanges()` and the changed objects are written back to the database. If "Revert" is clicked, I would like for all objects to get their original property values. What would be the code for that?

Thanks

Comment: Using EF Core 5+ there is a built-in `Clear` function.  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71784375/1812732

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is no revert or cancel changes operation in EF. Each entity has `ObjectStateEntry` in `ObjectStateManager`. State entry contains original and actual values so you can use original values to overwrite current values but you must do it manually for each entity. It will not reveret changes in navigation properties / relations.

The common way to "revert changes" is disposing context and reload entities. If you want to avoid reloading you must create clones of entities and modify those clones in new object context. If user cancel changes you will still have original entities.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Surely `Context.Refresh()` is a counter-example to your claim that there is no revert operation? Using `Refresh()` seems a better approach (i.e. more easily targeted at specific entities) than disposing the context and losing all tracked changes.

Comment: @robjb: No. Refresh is able to refresh only single entity or collection of entities which you manually define but refreshing functionality only affects simple properties (not relations). It also doesn't solve problem with added or deleted entities.

Answer (score 197):

Query ChangeTracker of DbContext for dirty items. Set deleted items state to unchanged and added items to detached. For modified items, use original values and set current values of the entry. Finally set state of modified entry to unchanged:

```
public void RollBack()
{
    var context = DataContextFactory.GetDataContext();
    var changedEntries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();

    foreach (var entry in changedEntries)
    {
        switch(entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Modified:
                entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                break;
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should probably set the original values to deleted entries as well. It's possible you first changed an item and deleted it after that.

Comment: Setting `State` to **EntityState.Unchanged** will override all values with `Original Values` as well so there is no need to call `SetValues` method.

Comment: Any idea what to do when Entries() throws? It's throwing for me for an entity that has a composite PK but the PK values were not yet set.

Comment: There is a scenario where this solution may not be the right one. It depends on whether saving happens independently of closing the edit dialog. If so, then here is a scenario to watch out for: 1) user opens edit dialog 2) edits and accepts changes (save is not performed here because save is a function of the bigger aggregate in parent window) 3) user takes a break/gets distracted/does other changes elsewhere, forgets if he/she edited that thing, and opens the edit dialog again 4) sees that changes are indeed good, cancels out of the window, then saves, unknowingly dismissing his changes

Comment: Cleaner version of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22098063/2498426

Comment: Mate, this is awesome!  Only modification I made is to use the the generic version of Entries<T>() so that it works for my respositories. This gives me more control and I can roll back per entity type.  Thanks!

Comment: Bug when state is Deleted and object property is changed, then state set to Unchanged.
`Deleted` must be set to `Modified` first, then to `Unchanged`.

Answer (score 38):

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).Reload();
```

Accroding to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> *Reloads the entity from the database overwriting any property values with values from the database. The entity will be in the Unchanged
>   state after calling this method.*

Note that reverting through the request to database has some drawbacks:

- network traffic
- DB overload
- the increased application response time

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me:

```
dataContext.customer.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, item);
```

Where `item` is the customer entity to be reverted.

Answer (score 14):

While this question predates Entity Framework Core, the EF Core developers have provided a simple solution to this problem.

As of EF Core 5.0, the `ChangeTracker` now provides a method to clear out tracked entities which is more efficient than detaching all changed entities.

```cs
context.ChangeTracker.Clear()
```

> Stops tracking all currently tracked entities.
>
> DbContext is designed to have a short lifetime where a new instance is created for each unit-of-work. This manner means all tracked entities are discarded when the context is disposed at the end of each unit-of-work. However, clearing all tracked entities using this method may be useful in situations where creating a new context instance is not practical.
>
> This method should always be preferred over detaching every tracked entity. Detaching entities is a slow process that may have side effects. This method is much more efficient at clearing all tracked entities from the context.
>
> Note that this method does not generate StateChanged events since entities are not individually detached.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-5.0)

At that point, you can retrieve the original values from the `DbContext`.

Comment: Detaching doesn't roll back changes in objects. Neither does ChangeTracker.Clear().

Comment: @Charles That is true. However, once the `ChangeTracker` is clear, the `DbContext` has the original values, which was the intent of the question. At that point, if you actually need the original values, you can simply fetch them from the `DbContext`.

Answer (score 13):

Easy way without tracking any changes.  It should be faster than looking at every entities.

```
public void Rollback()
{
    dataContext.Dispose();
    dataContext= new MyEntities(yourConnection);
}
```

Comment: Time of creating a single entitity object... which is a couple of ms (50 ms).  Looping through the collection may be a faster or longer depending of it's size.  Performance wise O(1) is rarely a problem compare to O(n). [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: Not following you - performance of disposing and recreating connection. I tested it on existing project and it finished somewhat faster then above `Rollback` procedure, which makes it far better choice if one wants to revert entire database state. Rollback could cherry pick tho.

Comment: 'n' means the number of objects.  Recreating connection take about 50 ms... O(1) means it is always the same time `50ms+0*n= 50ms`.  O(n) means the performance is influenced by the number of objects... performance is maybe `2ms+0.5ms*n`... so bellow 96 objects it would be faster but time would increase linearly with the amount of data.

Comment: If you are not going to cherry pick what is(n't) rolled back this is the way to go provided you are not worried about bandwidth.

Answer (score 7):

```
// Undo the changes of all entries. 
foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries()) 
{ 
    switch (entry.State) 
    { 
        // Under the covers, changing the state of an entity from  
        // Modified to Unchanged first sets the values of all  
        // properties to the original values that were read from  
        // the database when it was queried, and then marks the  
        // entity as Unchanged. This will also reject changes to  
        // FK relationships since the original value of the FK  
        // will be restored. 
        case EntityState.Modified: 
            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged; 
            break; 
        case EntityState.Added: 
            entry.State = EntityState.Detached; 
            break; 
        // If the EntityState is the Deleted, reload the date from the database.   
        case EntityState.Deleted: 
            entry.Reload(); 
            break; 
        default: break; 
    } 
}
```

It worked for me. However you must to reload your data from the context to bring the old data. Source [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-undo-the-changes-in-00aed3c4)

Answer (score 3):

As for me, better method to do it is to set `EntityState.Unchanged` on every entity you want to undo changes on. This assures changes are reverted on FK and has a bit more clear syntax.

Comment: Note: The changes will come back if the entity is changed again.

Answer (score 3):

"This worked for me:

```
dataContext.customer.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, item);
```

Where `item` is the customer entity to be reverted."

---

I have made tests with ObjectContext.Refresh in SQL Azure, and the "RefreshMode.StoreWins" fires a query against database for each entity and causes a performance leak. Based on microsoft documentation ():

**ClientWins : Property changes made to objects in the object context are not replaced with values from the data source. On the next call to SaveChanges, these changes are sent to the data source.**

**StoreWins : Property changes made to objects in the object context are replaced with values from the data source.**

ClientWins isn't a good ideia neither, because firing .SaveChanges will commit "discarded" changes to the datasource.

I dont' know what's the best way yet, because disposing the context and creating a new one is caused a exception with message: "The underlying provider failed on open" when I try to run any query on a new context created.

regards,

Henrique Clausing

Answer (score 3):

We are using EF 4, with the Legacy Object context. None of the above solutions directly answered this for me -- although it DID answer it in the long run by pushing me in the right direction.

We can't just dispose and rebuild the context because some of the objects we have hanging around in memory (damn that lazy loading!!) are still attached to the context but have children that are yet-to-be-loaded. For these cases we need to bump everything back to original values without hammering the database and without dropping the existing connection.

Below is our solution to this same issue:

```
    public static void UndoAllChanges(OurEntities ctx)
    {
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
            ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(~EntityState.Detached))
        {
            if (entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
            {
                ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entry.Entity);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be working fine in my context:

`Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(customer, EntityState.Unchanged);`

Comment: I believe this will prevent changes to the entity from persisting upon calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, but it will not return the entity values to the original values.  And if the entity state becomes modified from a later change, possibly all the previous modifications will be persisted upon saving?

Comment: Check this link http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-undo-the-changes-in-00aed3c4
It says that setting an entity to Unchaged state restores the original values "under the covers".

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of what Mrnka is talking about. The following method overwrites an entity's current values with the original values and **doesn't** call out the database. We do this by making use of the OriginalValues property of DbEntityEntry, and make use of reflection to set values in a generic way. (This works as of EntityFramework 5.0)

```
/// <summary>
/// Undoes any pending updates 
/// </summary>
public void UndoUpdates( DbContext dbContext )
{
    //Get list of entities that are marked as modified
    List<DbEntityEntry> modifiedEntityList = 
        dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

    foreach(  DbEntityEntry entity in modifiedEntityList ) 
    {
        DbPropertyValues propertyValues = entity.OriginalValues;
        foreach (String propertyName in propertyValues.PropertyNames)
        {                    
            //Replace current values with original values
            PropertyInfo property = entity.Entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            property.SetValue(entity.Entity, propertyValues[propertyName]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good ideas above, I chose to implement ICloneable and then a simple extension method.

Found here: [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

To be used as:

```
ReceiptHandler.ApplyDiscountToAllItemsOnReciept(LocalProductsOnReciept.Clone(), selectedDisc);
```

This way I was able to clone my product entities list, apply a discount to each item and not have to worry about reverting any changes on the original entity. No need to talk with the DBContext and ask for a refresh or work with the ChangeTracker. You might say I am not making full use of EF6 but this is a very nice and simple implementation and avoids a DB hit. I cannot say whether or not this has a performance hit.