# How to properly reload an object from the database in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an `Invoice` entity with one `LineItem` in its line item colletion and then add another `LineItem` to it. I now want to discard this addition and refresh the `Invoice` from the database and therefore use `dbContext.Entry(invoice).Reload()`.

However, the invoice still has two line items after this call, where the second one seems to be a copy of the first one. What is the reason for this and how can I solve it?

Comment: this maybe can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466677/undo-changes-in-entity-framework-entities