# Entity Framework incorrect data results after query

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Ok so I have this query

```
  public bool Save(PresseViewModel p)
    {
        var presse = PresseService.Instance.Get(p.Id);

        presse.title = p.Title;
        presse.sammenfatning = p.Sammenfatning;
        presse.HTML = p.HTML;

        try
        {
            PresseService.Instance.Save(presse);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to update an existing record with only selected fields.
The model has 20+ fields but now I am only trying to update 3 fields.

What I did is I fetched first the original record from db, then populate those fields with new values and **Save!!** then all good!.

**Now the problem is**

What if the ".Save " failed? and moved to Catch Exception, so as usual nothing will be saved, original values will remain the same right? Ok so move on and ignore it,

Ok now I want to get that same record and populate it to my page, and then weird things happens, it gave me instead incorrect result, the 3 fields it render was the 3 fields I am trying to save previously (but failed to save),

I assume the problem is this line

```
    var presse = PresseService.Instance.Get(p.Id);

    presse.title = p.Title;
    presse.sammenfatning = p.Sammenfatning;
    presse.HTML = p.HTML
```

This line will store somewhere in memory (or somewhere else) regardless if it was saved or not, so the next time I query for that ID is it will give that values I set before.

Now my question is how can I avoid it or what is the fix for this,
and as much as possible I dont want to force query from database using this line `_db.Entry<Pressemeddelelser>(result).Reload();`

Comment: Are you using a singleton context or something?  Once the save fails, your context should get destroyed / rolled back, so there shouldn't be an issue with it caching the prior values.  Also, as a general rule, swallowing an exception in this manner and just returning false is asking for trouble.  I hope that was just to demonstrate your issue and not real code.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Yes I am using a singleton, in my situation regardless of it was saved or not it still caching my "supposed to saved values", the save was failed so I am expecting the original results and not the "supposed to saved values".

Comment: Possible duplicate?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466677/undo-changes-in-entity-framework-entities

Comment: I think this question might be what you are looking for [dbcontext-discard-changes-without-disposing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437083/dbcontext-discard-changes-without-disposing)