# What if I call DbContext.Dispose without calling DbContext.SaveChanges?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, rollback

I am looking for a way to roll back entity changes.  I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22098063/701346) which shows how to set entity state, but I am wondering what happens if I simply dispose of my `dbContext` instance without calling `dbContext.SaveChanges()` or manipulating the entity states.

The code I wrote to do so definitely works, but am I leaving anything in an unstable state by rejecting changes in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what happens if I simply dispose of my dbContext instance without calling dbContext.SaveChanges() or manipulating the entity states

Nothing. The instances that were previously attached to the now disposed `DbContext` instance continue to exist as any normal instances would assuming there is a handle on those instances somewhere by something. If there is not the memory will be release and eventually garbage collected as any other normal instance of something would if there is no handle to it. The state of the entities in memory stays as is, nothing in memory is automatically reverted back. The database store also stays "as is" meaning there is no call from the DbContext to the datastore.

> am I leaving anything in an unstable state by rejecting changes in this way

No, at least not in the data store. In memory it is hard to say, it depends on where the code left off and what the dependencies were on the modifications up until that point. Lets assume its a stateless asp.net application, maybe the request simply ends and in this case nothing unstable should happen with any of the following requests as they should retrieve anything needed back from the data store.

If its something more long lived like a windows app then you might have to manually make sure that any pointers/handles to instances that were previously being tracked are either updated with the now reverted in-memory state or release those pointers.

As far as any new DbContext instances are concerned they all operate independent of each other so there is no continuation between them. The new DbContext does not know about state being tracked or state that had been tracked by any other DbContext instance.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually addresses my question.  Instead of explaining how disposal works, it focuses on the entities within the DbContext itself.  Anyway, what you said makes sense.  The entities in the context will exist like any other object to be GC'd whenever there is no reference to them.  If I don't call `.SaveChanges()`, the changes will not be pushed to the database.  I'll most likely be marking this as answer shortly

Answer (score 4):

Calling the `Dispose()` method of a class implementing `IDisposable` means you're telling the library "I am done with this object. I will no longer use it. You may clear up as needed." This is not specific to Entity Framework.

For most classes, attempts to continue using the object after calling `Dispose()` will fail, sometimes with an explicit exception alerting you to the problem, sometimes by an internal exception caused by corrupted object state. You should not assume Entity Framework is an exception to that: after calling `dbContext.Dispose()`, you should no longer use the context referenced by `dbContext`.

However, there's nothing stopping you from creating a *new* context immediately afterwards:

```
dbContext.Dispose();
dbContext = new DbContext();
```

This new context will have absolutely no recollection of any unsaved changes you made in the old context. There are plenty of good cases in which this approach is the most practical.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will be in unstable state, so no worries. If you attempt to call context after you disposed it you will get `ObjectDisposedException` otherwise it is legal to dispose it if you don't need it anymore.