# Delete statement conflicts with Reference constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I assume this has a very simple answer. I am brand new to entity framework and I am creating a test application consisting of `Contacts` and `Groups` as objects/entities.

Here is my code to delete a group:

```
    private void button_DeleteGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var _selectedGroup = dataGridView_Groups.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as Group;

        try
        {
            cgContext.Groups.Remove(_selectedGroup);
            cgContext.SaveChanges();

            PopulateGroupGrid();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully deleted group from database!");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Failed to delete group from database.\r\n\r\n" + ex); }
    }
```

If I delete a group that a contact belongs to, to test referential integrity, an exception is thrown (as it should):

> "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Contacts_dbo.Groups_Group_Id". The conflict occurred in
>   database "ContactGroups", table "dbo.Contacts", column
>   'Group_Id'. The statement has been terminated."

I then catch this exception and display a message to the user. If I then go to add a new group or contact or do anything, the transaction fails with the same exception as before:

> "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Contacts_dbo.Groups_Group_Id". The conflict occurred in
>   database "ContactGroups", table "dbo.Contacts", column
>   'Group_Id'. The statement has been terminated."

So, obviously i'm not clearing / ending a transaction or something when the initial exception occurs. What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 1):

#### Rolling back from an invalid entity state in Entity Framework

In the case that a constraint violation, or other invalid entity state exists in Entity Framework, it is necessary to revert the state to a valid/good state in order to continue to persist changes.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466677/undo-changes-in-entity-framework-entities) describes how to do that in detail.

#### Background - why FK constraint violation occurs

There exists a foreign key constraint between the Contacts table and the Groups table. Each contact has a reference to a group, per the foreign key (FK) `FK_dbo.Contacts_dbo.Groups_Group_Id`.

In the code above, a group is removed. Before doing this, either a check should be done to ensure that there are no Contacts that reference (are in) that group, or the Contacts in that group should be deleted. The approach will depend on your business logic.

Once the dependency has been removed (i.e. any Contacts that reference Group via Contacts.GroupId), then the Group can be removed without a FK violation.

Comment: Sorry, But this isn't about that error occurring. I am forcing it to occur so that I can test referential integrity. I want to know why the same exception continues to be thrown with other CRUD operation immediately after the exception is thrown the first time.

Comment: OK, so you're expecting the exception then. If you're saying that the problem is that you can't roll it back so that other changes can be tested, then have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466677/undo-changes-in-entity-framework-entities

Comment: Okay thanks, That sort of helped. This seems like it should have a more standardized answer. Thank again though :)

Comment: Sure. Sorry, I misread the question -- I should have picked up on the "as it should"!

Answer (score 1):

use WillCascadeOnDelete(true) for WithOptional

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
  .HasMany<Child>(c => c.Children)
  .WithOptional(x => x.Parent)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

use Include

```
  var adv = db.Adv.Include(b => b.Features)
                  .Include(b => b.AdvDetails)
                  .Include(b => b.AdvGallery)
                  .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
  db.Adv.Remove(adv);
```

> for .HasMany(...).WithMany(...) Include is ok

Answer (score -1):

**Entity Framework is also called Persistence Store.** Because it persists status of an entity as well as original and modified values. It actually **tracks** entity.

EntityStateEntry has entry for each entity in EF. So when you call `cgContext.Groups.Remove(_selectedGroup)`, it changes entity's state to deleted.

Now, you are deleting a group which has persons associated to it. So Referential integrity won't let you delete the `_selectedGroup` and you get the error. But the status of `_selectedGroup` was left as `Deleted`. Now when you go to add a new group, after adding group you call `cgContext.SaveChange()`. This tries to do both save changes - the new group added, and `_selectedGroup` deleted. But again, the deletion violates FK, and you get the same error.

To make it work, you can use `TransactionScope`. See usage [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) I will probably end up using that or creating a rollback method like this:                                         public void Rollback()
{
    dataContext.Dispose();
    dataContext= new MyEntities(yourConnection);
} Is the transactionScope a better way to go?