# Entity Framework: SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave vs SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the difference between `SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave` and `SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave` in Entity Framework? When to use `SaveOptions.None`?

These options are provided in `objectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)`.

Can any of these option, in any way, be used to reverse the changes made by `objectContext.SaveChanges()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're two entirely different things. Note how `SaveOptions` has the `Flags` attribute: this indicates you can combine multiple flags, in this case to make `SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave | SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave`.

And if you're wondering about something like `SaveOptions.None | SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave`, then keep in mind that `SaveOptions.None` is the zero value, so this is just a long-winded way of writing `SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave`.

So you use `SaveOptions.None` when you want neither `SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave` nor `SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave`.

> Can any of these option, in any way, be used to reverse the changes made by `objectContext.SaveChanges()`?

In the context? If you *don't* include `SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave`, then all changes will be preserved locally as unsaved. All added entities will remain in "added" state, all modified entities will remain in "modified" state, all deleted entities will still be available by explicitly requesting your context's deleted entities. Attempting to save again will likely fail, as the database has already been updated. You can then use the regular methods for reverting unsaved changes, but it requires a lot of manual work on your part, it requires manually looking up the original values of all properties and restoring that value. A detailed example of how to do this is, I think, beyond the scope of this question, but see [Undo changes in entity framework entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466677/undo-changes-in-entity-framework-entities).

In the database? This requires even more work on your part, and may not even be possible at all: once an entity with a server-generated column (e.g. auto-increment key, or row version field), it is generally impossible to restore it with those exact same values it originally had.