# How to make correct clone of the List<MyObject>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

```
List<MyObject> a1 = new List<MyObject>();

var new1 = a1;
```

Now if I change `a1` then `new1` is going to be changed as well.

So my question is how *to make a clone of **a1** correctly?*

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This wont `Clone` each item in the list but will create you a new list

```
var new1 = new List<MyObject>(a1);
```

If you want to clone each Item in the list you can implement `ICloneable` on `MyObject`

```
var new1 = new List<MyObject>(a1.Select(x => x.Clone()));
```

EDIT:
To make it a bit clearer both will copy the elements from list `a1` into a new list. You just need to decide if you want to have new `MyObject`s or keep the originals. If you want to clone `MyObject` you will need a way to clone them which typically is done through `ICloneable`.

Comment: How is his solution not treating all items?

Comment: var new1 = new List<MyObject>(a1); only works for value types, you should update your answer.

Comment: var new1 = new List<MyObject>(a1.Select(x => x.Clone() as MyObject));

Answer (score 4):

Or, you could do something like this:

```
public static class CloneClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Clones a object via shallow copy
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Object Type to Clone</typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj">Object to Clone</param>
    /// <returns>New Object reference</returns>
    public static T CloneObject<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        if (obj == null) return null;
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo inst = obj.GetType().GetMethod("MemberwiseClone",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (inst != null)
            return (T)inst.Invoke(obj, null);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var new1 = CloneClass.CloneObject<List<<MyObject>>(a1);
```

Comment: You have one too many "<" 's.
Should be <List<MyObject>>

Answer (score 1):

I think the general practice is to avoid using [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) because it's not clear if it's a Shallow vs Deep copy of the object.

More on that here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx

A fairly common solution has been to use the BinaryFormatter class to serialize/derialize an object and return the new instance, but with the caveat that the class must be serializable:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213649/1212407

Assuming the above, you could do:

```
var clonedList = originaList.DeepClone();
```