# Make an independent duplication of a List<T>

Tags: c#

I make two List< Test> called **listA** and **listB**.
I save a peace of data in **listA**.
I copy the data from **listA** to **listB**.
I change the data in **listB**.
When I change the data in **listB** it also changes in **listA** – is it posible to avoid this?

I hope you can help me out there :o)

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static void Test()
    {
        List<Test> listA = new List<Test>();
        List<Test> listB = new List<Test>();

        listA.Add(new Test { Name = "A" });
        listB.AddRange(listA);

        //I change the data in listB and the data in listA also get changed. 
        listB.First().Name = "B";
        Console.WriteLine("listA: {0} listB: {1}", listA.First().Name, listB.First().Name);

        //Can I avoid the change of data in listA?
    }
```

Comment: change class Test to Struct Test and see what happens

Comment: You have a misconception here. Regardless of the `List` instances being different, the `Test` instances they contain are the same, so if you change something inside a `Test` instance, it's going to be changed regardless of which `List` instance you accessed it thru.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622211/how-to-make-correct-clone-of-the-listmyobject

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do a deep copy an object in .Net (C# specifically)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create new instances of the `Test` object.

You could add a copy method to your test class to make it a bit easier to copy the members using `MemberwiseClone`, this will be good if you have losts of properties to copy without needing big select statments to populate each property.

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Test Copy()
    {
        return (Test)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Then you can use where needed in your code.

```
  List<Test> listA = new List<Test>();
  List<Test> listB = new List<Test>();
  listA.Add(new Test { Name = "A" });

  listB.AddRange(listA.Select(x => x.Copy()));
```

Comment: Using MemberwiseClone turns out to be the best way for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to copy the objects in `listA` when adding them to `listB`:

```
listB.AddRange(listA.Select(t => new Test { Name = t.Name }));
```

At the moment, you are just copying the references in `listA` into `listB`, and these references point to the same object. This is why modifying them through `listA` makes the changes visible in `listB`.

Comment: And you could encapsulate the copying part into a method, called something like `Clone()`.

Comment: Thanks Lee! My real Test Clas has 15 properties. Are there a diferent apporach than writing them all: listB.AddRange(listA.Select(t => new Test { Name = t.Name, Name2 = t.Name2 ... Name15 = t.Name15 }).ToList()); ?

Answer (score 0):

This also works because Test obj in listB is a instance different than Test obj in listA

```
 listA.ForEach((item) =>
    {
        listB.Add(new Test {Name = item.Name});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For more complex objects you can implement a clone method as described in the comment above:

```
public Test Clone()
{
     return new Test { Name = this.Name};
}
```

The code above would be modified as follows:

```
listB.AddRange(listA.Select(t => t.Clone()));
```

There is also an ICloneable interface in .NET but it is not recommend to use this interface. I included a link to another question that contains a discussion of this interface.

[Why should I implement ICloneable in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c)