# Clone extension not working

Tags: c#

What am I missing below? When I try **list.Clone()** Clone doesn't show up in list.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/222640/139698

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
        list.Clone() //There is no Clone method in the list
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> listToClone) where T : ICloneable
    {
        return listToClone.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement `ICloneable` interface on `Customer` class. Also as the extension method has been defined for `IList<T>` where `T is ICloneable`, you may want to use below syntax

```
        IList<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
        list.Clone();
```

The `Clone()` extension method will not be visible if `Customer` doesn't implement `ICloneable`

Comment: There is no need to use `IList` here, `List` would have worked as well, even though the extension method is for `IList`.

Answer (score 5):

Customer has to implement ICloneable because your generic condition says T has to implement ICloneable.

`public class Customer : ICloneable`

Comment: like this? return this.MemberwiseClone();

Comment: That's a way of implementing the Clone function, or you can write your own Clone. What matters is full implementation of the ICloneable interface, no matter how it's done.