# How to copy one list to another in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list that I want to copy to another list.

I have 'employeeAddressDataToSave' List and I want to copy this list to 'employeeAddressDataToSaveReturn' List.

I'm using the following code to do that. After I set this, further down the road, I'm updating employeeAddressDataToSave List. Those changes are automatically getting to 'employeeAddressDataToSaveReturn' list. I don't want my employeeAddressDataToSaveReturn list to be updated with changes to employeeAddressDataToSave . Is there a way to do that?

```
employeeAddressDataToSaveReturn = new List<Address>(employeeAddressDataToSave);
```

Comment: Search for deep copy, deep clone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758044/copying-a-list-to-another-new-list-should-not-reference-to-old-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952185/how-do-i-copy-items-from-list-to-list-without-foreach

Comment: You need to implement Prototype Design Pattern to solve your issue to avoid changes in one list not to affect another list.

Answer (score 3):

You are performing a [shallow copy of the list, you need to perform a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) of it. The list are two separate lists, but the items in the list are shared between them. If you edit a item, not the list itself, the edit will show up in both.

You will need to provide some method to copy `Address` when making the new list.

```
employeeAddressDataToSaveReturn = new List<Address>(employeeAddressDataToSave.Select(x=>x.Copy());`
```

This now calls the `Address.Copy()` method (which you will need to write) and it will return a copy of itself.

Here is a quick example, you did not show `Address` so I will have to make one up

```
class Address
{
    public string Street {get;set;}
    public string Zip {get;set;}

    public Address Copy()
    {
        var result = new Address();
        result.Street = this.Street;
        retult.Zip = this.Zip;
        return result;
    }
}
```

If `Address` contains nested [mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274193/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mutable-and-immutable-string-in-c) classes you will need to write a `Copy()` method for them too and call `Copy()` recursively.

Answer (score 2):

Your lists don't contain address data items, they contain *references* to address data items. The lists are separate, meaning that if you add a reference to an address to list2, it is not added to list1:

```
var list1 = GetList1();
Console.WriteLine(list1.Count); // 3
var list2 = new List(list1);
list2.Add(new AddressData("John Doe", "Foo street", "12345"); 
Console.WriteLine(list1.Count); // 3
Console.WriteLine(list2.Count); // 4
```

However if you edit an *item* in list1, you will also modify it in the other list

```
Console.WriteLine(list1[2].Name); // Bob
Console.WriteLine(list2[2].Name); // Bob
list2[2].Name = "Jim";
Console.WriteLine(list1[2].Name); // Jim <-- Changed
Console.WriteLine(list2[2].Name); // Jim
```

If you want to make a deep copy, implement a copy/clone method on your address class, and copy the whole list, item by item

```
list2 = list1.Select(a => a.Copy()).ToList();
```