# List<T> copied from same object, properties updated in both places

Tags: c#

I've done a lot of reading on copying/cloning objects in C# and I was trying to work from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977841/how-do-i-change-my-new-list-without-changing-the-original-list), but my situation is a little different.

I have a list of question/answer pairs being returned from the database. I want to use that to create two lists for parent and child objects. When I do that, any changes I make to the child are reflected in the parent.

I've tried several permutations of creating new lists, cloning, etc, but always end up with the same result.

```
List<QuestionVM> questionlist = productRepository.GetQuestions();
parent.Questions = AddQuestions(true, parent, questionlist);
child.Questions = AddQuestions(false, child, questionlist);

private List<QuestionVM> AddQuestions(bool parent, Line line, List<QuestionVM> questions)
{
    //shouldn't this create a new object, not just a reference?
    List<QuestionVM> qs = new List<QuestionVM>(questions);

    if (parent)
    {
        return qs.Where(w => w.ShowOnParent).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return qs.ToList(); 
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It does create a new `List<T>` object, but items in that list are references to the same items as in the initial list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough to just create copy of the list, because items in both old and new lists will still refer to the same objects.

You [need to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c) implement [ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface(or just your own [custom method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536349/why-no-icloneablet)) for your objects and call clone for each original object while creating copy list:

```
public class QuestionVM: ICloneable
{
     public Object Clone()
     {
          return new QuestionVM(this.prop1, this.prop2);
     }
}

...

private List<QuestionVM> AddQuestions(bool parent, Line line, List<QuestionVM> questions)
{
...
return qs
    .Where(w => w.ShowOnParent)
    .Select(obj => (VMQuestion)obj.Clone())
    .ToList();
...
}
```

**P.S.:** If `VMQuestion` contains fields of other complex types then they have to provide Clone method as well.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much. Is there a difference between your Clone() method and using this:    

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

Comment: @jlkmpls Yes, you can use `this.MemberwiseClone();` if VMQuestion constists of immutable members. It will be simpler than manual instantiation. But if members are of more complex mutable types then you will have to either augment `MemberwiseClone` [with some recursion](http://yangliucsharp.blogspot.ru/2013/10/deep-clone-vs-shallow-clone.html) or create new copy manually with specific constructors.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is still interested in this. You can use automapper to make deepcopy of an object.

Comment: Would be great if you add some code using automapper (from the question, precisely), some basic instructions to get it working and some links for further documentation.