# Updating new list of objects updates main list

Tags: c#, linq, clone

I have a list of objects which gets when updated using linq `ForEach`. Problem is that data is getting updated with reference type. I want to update it with value type

I tried to do cloning but it didn't work (not sure whether I'm following the right procedure).

Answer (score 1):

Your list `newSetRatio` is emptied inside `if` condition. If that condition returns `false`, it will contain the values from previous iteration. Since it is populated in every iteration, outside of condition, whenever condition returns `false` all items from `assetSharingRatios` will be added without list being cleared previously. So in case `assetSharingRatios` has not changed and your codnition returns `false`, `newSetRatio` will have all duplicates. And if condition keeps resulting in `false`, items in `newSetRatio` will triple and so on.

Another point is your last line of code `contributePartnersData.assetSharingRatio = newSetRatio;`
If you fix `newSetRatio` behavior, then last item added into `contributingPartnersData` will get new `assetSharingRatio` values whenever `if` condition is `false`. Not sure if this is intended, looks a bit strange. Is this why those last three lines of code are outside of 'if`?

Comment: I tried placing the line `newSetRatio = new List<AssetRatios>();` outside the if condition but it didn't work and whenever I change the value of a list `newSetRatio` it also affects `assetSharingRatio` the problem is similar to the problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977841/how-do-i-change-my-new-list-without-changing-the-original-list) but I tried the solution provided there but it didn't work

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. So when you do `.Foreach` on `newSetRatio' it updates values in `assetSharingRatios` and that is a problem? If so, then change `newSetRatio.AddRange(assetSharingRatios.Where....` into
`newSetRatio = new List<AssetRatios>(assetSharingRatios.Where...` and let me know if that helps