# Assign List<T> to another List<T> by value not reference

Tags: c#, list

Ok so I have List list1  that I pulled from db and I want to temporary save this to List list2, perform some operation on my list1 save it to db and then play with list2 and save it to db. The problem is that because is is passed by reference once I change some fields in list1, list2 is already updated.

Is there any way to pass whole list as a value not reference?

Here is some code to make it clearer :

```
var CurrentMenuItems = dbContext.menu_items.Where(m => m.optgroup == currentGroup && m.day_id == menuItem.day_id).ToList();

           List<menu_item> MenuItemsToBeEditedAfterSubmitChanges = CurrentMenuItems;// we need to store this by value, so we can update it later


            byte ItemIncrease = 50; // To store temp value so we can avoid duplicate entry for item number 

            foreach (var item in CurrentMenuItems)
            {
                item.optgroup = nextGroup;
                item.item = ItemIncrease;

                ItemIncrease++; 
            }

            var menuItemsToBeReplaced = dbContext.menu_items.Where(m => m.optgroup == nextGroup && m.day_id == menuItem.day_id).ToList(); // we want to move all items within this group

            dbContext.SubmitChanges();

            foreach (var item in menuItemsToBeReplaced)
            {
                item.optgroup = currentGroup;

                item.item = (byte)(item.item - 1);

            }

            dbContext.SubmitChanges();

            // After first save, update the first group of menu items

            foreach (var item in MenuItemsToBeEditedAfterSubmitChanges)
            {

                item.optgroup = nextGroup;
                item.item = (byte)(item.item + 1);

            }

            dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Please post some code to show us exactly what you are doing and where it's going wrong. It is not clear exactly how deep you need this copy to be and your question is inviting speculative answers. I'll remove my downvote when this question becomes clearer.

Comment: You can clone the list as shown here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c

Comment: What kind of elements are stored in the List?

Comment: @AdamBielecki a quick google search for "deep copy" would have given you the correct answer. I would downvote but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the `List<T>` constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`. Example:

```
List<int> originalList = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2 };
List<int> copiedList = new List<int>(originalList);
copiedList[2] = 3; // originalList[2] still is 2
```

Comment: Or u can copiedList.AddRange(originalList)

Comment: Uhmm, have you tried with a reference type instead of a value type?

Comment: @Steve the result would not change based on what type you use to instantiate the generic `List<T>` class. The question was about shallow-vs-deep copying of lists, not items in lists.

Answer (score 3):

Just Another Yet Solution:

```
IList<string> f = new List<string>();

var t = f.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<object> list2 = new List<object>(list1);
```

This should prevent you from referencing the other list because the values are copied.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that the given answer work only for value type.
For reference type you should implement a clone method that copy all the data on a new instance of the same class
Then for each element in the list you add in another list the cloned object

Comment: You are on the right track, now add an example and you have the right answer.

Comment: @Steve the question did not ask about copying all the items in the list; it asked only about making a list copy that does not immediately reference another list.