# XmlNodeConverter only supports deserializing XmlDocuments error when using Json DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization

I've the following class;

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public XmlCDataSection sName
    {
        get { return new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(Name); }
        set { Name = value.Value; }
    }
}
```

I've the following function to take a List<> and copy it's contents;

```
private static T CloneList<T>(T source)
{
    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
}
```

But in my code when I try;

```
  List<MyClass> oMyClassList = new List<MyClass>();

  MyClass oMyClass = new MyClass();
  oMyClass.Name = "Hello World's";

  oMyClassList.Add(oMyClass);

  List<MyClass> oMyClonedClassList = new List<MyClass>(CloneList(oMyClassList));
```

At the point of executing the following

```
List<MyClass> oMyClonedClassList = new List<MyClass>(CloneList(oMyClassList));
```

I get the error  `XmlNodeConverter only supports deserializing XmlDocuments`.  The problem occurs because I've added XmlCDataSection into the class.

How can I get around this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this problem by changing my CloneList code to the following

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    T objResult;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Position = 0;
        objResult = (T)bf.Deserialize(ms);
    }
    return objResult;
}
```

As provided by [Ajith][1] here [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/853645/ajith "ajith".

Also, to each of the classes that need to be cloned, I had to add `[Serializable]` at the top of each class as I was getting the exception 'Not marked as serializable'