# How to use c# lists not be reference

Tags: c#, list

Regarding the following code:

main()

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();
List<int> b = new List<int>();

a.Add(2);
a = add(a, 3);
b = add(a, 4);
b.Add(5);
a.Add(6);
```

function

```
static List<int> add(List<int> l, int x)
{
    l.Add(x);
    return l;
}
```

What I would like is that the result would be:
a(2,3,6) and b(2,3,4,5).

In the end, both lists contain (2,3,4,5,6).

I understand that this may happens because a,b are just pointers to the start of the list. How could i achieve my desired result?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877596/copying-list-values/20877640#20877640

Comment: Why do you have the `add` method? It looks totally pointless

Comment: Just return a different list from the one received as parameter.

Comment: @johnnycardy it seems pointless in this example. but it would make my question easier understandable. This is how i could use my function: a.add(1); for (i=2;i<10;i++){b=add(a,i); do_things_with_b();}. So in the first iteration i would run the function with b(1,2), in the second iteration with b(1,3)... until b(1,10)

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis - How about an extension method like `public static IEnumerable<T> And<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item) { foreach (var value in source) { yield return value; } yield return item; }` which you could then use like `var b = a.And(i);` or if you really need a list: `var b = a.And(i).ToList();`? Would even work for `var b = a.And(3); b = b.And(4);` (or `var b = a.And(3).And(4);` for that matter) - now `b` would enumerate everything from `a`, then `3` and then `4`.

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis Have a look at my answer. I'm really curious to know if it's a valid solution - so much shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a complete example that does what you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> a = new List<int>();
        List<int> b = new List<int>();

        a.Add(2);
        a = add(a, 3);
        b = add(a, 4);
        b.Add(5);
        a.Add(6);

        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var item in b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    static List<int> add(List<int> l, int x)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>(l);
        result.Add(x);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although it works, it seems overkill to create a new list every time an item is added.

Comment: @johnnycardy It works, it is simple and it is the only thing I can think of at this time for this requirement. If creating a new list every time is an issue, I'm guessing there would not be a requirement to make something work this way.

Answer (score 2):

As you want two separate lists, you have to create another list in the code. If you want the method to return a new list, and get the result that you desired, you would need to create it before adding the item to it:

```
static List<int> add(List<int> l, int x) {
  l = new List<int>(l);
  l.Add(x);
  return l;
}
```

Comment: This solution does not meet the requirements: it adds to the `a` list the `4` value (see OP's example). Add `x` to the outputted list.

Comment: will this still change a to (2,3,4,6)?

Comment: @Bolu: Nope, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. Delete your `add` method, and include `System.Linq`. Then you can use the `ToList()` method to create a copy.

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();
List<int> b; //Don't instantiate - it would be overwritten anyway

a.Add(2);
a.Add(3);

b = a.ToList(); //Create a copy of 'a'
b.Add(4);
b.Add(5);

a.Add(6);
```