# Cloning Objects: Is serialization - deserialization a good practice for cloning objects?

Tags: c#, clone

I need to clone lists in different parts of the system I'm working on and I came up with the below solution, but I'm still concerned about it's performance I've been wondering if that is a good method at all. So I decided to post it here so that I can find if there is any problem or flaw related to this method of cloning objects. And if it is a bad move, I'd like to know what is the best approach.

My extension method for cloning a list:

```
    public static List<T> Clone<T>(this List<T> input)
    {
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream Mems = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            Serializer.Serialize(Mems, input);
            var Deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize(Mems) as List<T>;
            return Deserialized;
        }
    }
```

Update: Assuming T is a value type (Always)

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c

Comment: @Shekhar: If the T is a value time, then does that change the memory location of the original value in the second list. I think the memory location remains the same meaning the list is not cloned but copied.

Comment: @Shekhar: I'm speaking about VALUE type not a reference type that implement IClonable

Comment: I think it is at least not bad practice, so this method should work fine. Are you using xml serialization just because to support objects without `Serializable` attribute?

Comment: you should update that in the question

Comment: @nikis: Yeah the T is always (in this case) a value type, so there is no Serailizable attribute in this case.

Comment: Value types are always copied, so you don't have to worry about deep cloning (it's always new). For reference types it's a little trickier, since `ICloneable` does not guarantee a deep clone ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Your serialization method is probably the easiest way to deal with reference types.

Answer (score -1):

That adds a considerable performance hit and wastes memory (XML is verbose).

Shallow clone:

```
public static List<T> Clone<T>(this List<T> input)
{
    return new List<T>(input);
}
```

Deep clone:

```
public static List<T> Clone<T>(this List<T> input) where T : ICloneable
{
    var cloned = new List<T>(input.Capacity);
    cloned.AddRange(input.Select(item => (T) item.Clone()));
    return cloned;
}
```

Comment: This is shallow cloning.

Comment: refer to my comment under my post

Comment: @usr - No need for downvote.  He specified value types so that's completely irrelevant.  But I added a deep clone anyways.

Comment: Your deep clone is flawed, because `ICloneable` doesn't guarantee a deep clone ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: Value types can have reference members which would be skipped by this procedure.

Comment: @Setsu - No, it doesn't.  But if he's closing his own types he would implement a deep copy.

Comment: Does this deep cloning method really have a higher performance comparing to my serialization method? Saying this because the LINQ is already slow unless you do PLINQ, and each object must have its own cloning function, THAT cloning function is important, so all these things together make it pretty slow as well!

Comment: @Arrr - Yes, this should be far faster if implemented correctly.  I could benchmark for you if I had a type.

Comment: @Zer0: Well I recommend you to make it parallel before the select, it would considerably add up performance. Higher CPU usage, faster cloning

Comment: @Arrrr - That would only make sense if the clone is very expensive.  There's overhead to doing things in parallel.  My guess is PLINQ likely wouldn't even do this in parallel in most cases.  But back to the point - this will be much, much faster than XML serialization and use less memory.

Comment: @Zer0: It does do it in parallel, though using Parallel Foreach is also possible to maximize the performance