# Why does this method result in an infinite loop?

Tags: c#, linq, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

One of my coworkers came to me with a question about this method that results in an infinite loop. The actual code is a bit too involved to post here, but essentially the problem boils down to this:

```
private IEnumerable<int> GoNuts(IEnumerable<int> items)
{
    items = items.Select(item => items.First(i => i == item));
    return items;
}
```

This *should* (you would think) just be a very inefficient way to create a copy of a list. I called it with:

```
var foo = GoNuts(new[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});
```

The result is an infinite loop. Strange.

I think that modifying the parameter is, stylistically a bad thing, so I changed the code slightly:

```
var foo = items.Select(item => items.First(i => i == item));
return foo;
```

That worked. That is, the program completed; no exception.

More experiments showed that this works, too:

```
items = items.Select(item => items.First(i => i == item)).ToList();
return items;
```

As does a simple

```
return items.Select(item => .....);
```

Curious.

It's clear that the problem has to do with reassigning the parameter, but only if evaluation is deferred beyond that statement. If I add the `ToList()` it works.

I have a general, vague, idea of what's going wrong. It looks like the `Select` is iterating over its own output. That's a little bit strange in itself, because typically an `IEnumerable` will throw if the collection it's iterating changes.

What I don't understand, because I'm not intimately familiar with the internals of how this stuff works, is why re-assigning the parameter causes this infinite loop.

Is there somebody with more knowledge of the internals who would be willing to explain why the infinite loop occurs here?

Comment: `items` is reassigned before the iteration starts. That's why you get a recursive iterator. This doesn't happen if you call `ToList`, as the assignment is performed after the iteration in that case.

Comment: While not an answer, you should know that there are many ways to clone a list. Here's some great answers on how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c

Comment: Thanks, @MiniRagnarok. I wasn't really trying to clone a list, but rather using that simple code to illustrate the infinite recursion behavior of a much more complex method.

Comment: Downvoters? Any particular reason for the downvotes? Something wrong with the question? A reason is customary.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The key to answering this is *deferred execution*. When you do this

```
items = items.Select(item => items.First(i => i == item));
```

you do *not* iterate the `items` array passed into the method. Instead, you assign it a new `IEnumerable<int>`, which references itself back, and starts iterating only when the caller starts enumerating the results.

That is why all your other fixes have dealt with the problem: all you needed to do is to stop feeding `IEnumerable<int>` back to itself:

- Using `var foo` breaks self-reference by using a different variable,
- Using `return items.Select...` breaks self-reference by not using intermediate variables at all,
- Using `ToList()` breaks self-reference by avoiding deferred execution: by the time `items` is re-assigned, old `items` has been iterated over, so you end up with a plain in-memory `List<int>`.

> But if it's feeding on itself, how does it get anything at all?

That's right, it does not get anything! The moment you try iterating `items` and ask it for the first item, the deferred sequence asks the sequence fed to it for the first item to process, which means that the sequence is asking itself for the first item to process. At this point, it's [turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down), because in order to return the first item to process the sequence must first get the first item to process from itself.

Comment: But if it's feeding on itself, how does it get anything at all? It's like the query is consuming the original input and then its own output. But it seems like the only way it could do that is if the output was being appended to the original input, or perhaps a copy of the original input.

Comment: @JimMischel The issue is on `First` (`items.First`), and it will be called at least once because the `Select` iterates over original sequence - use `argItems` and `localItems` for names to see it more clear (will be `localItems.First...`)

Comment: So it's not consuming its own output (i.e. creating an infinite sequence of items), but instead stuck on trying to find the first item to iterate over? Interesting . . .

Comment: A little time with ILDASM and single-stepping in the debugger confirmed this. The call to `First` tries to get the first item in the collection so it can start iterating. Which causes a recursive call to `Select` and `First` ... and, as you said: "Turtles all the way down." Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

> It looks like the Select is iterating over its own output

You are correct.  You are returning a *query* that iterates over itself.

The key is that you reference `items` *within the lambda*.  The `items` reference is not resolved ("closed over") until the query iterates, at which point `items` now references the query instead of the source collection.  *That's* where the self-reference occurs.

Picture a deck of cards with a sign in front of it labelled `items`.  Now picture a man standing beside the deck of cards whose assignment is to iterate the collection called `items`.  But then you move the sign from the deck to the *man*.  When you ask the man for the first "item" - he looks for the collection marked "items" - which is now him!  So he asks himself for the first item, which is where the circular reference occurs.

When you assign the result to a *new* variable, you then have a query that iterates over a *different* collection, and so does not result in an infinite loop.

When you call `ToList`, you hydrate the query to a new collection and also do not get an infinite loop.

Other things that would break the circular reference:

- Hydrating items *within the lambda* by calling `ToList`
- Assigning `items` to another variable and referencing *that* within the lambda.

Comment: But if the query is set to iterate over its own output, shouldn't the result be an empty sequence? How can it iterate over the original collection *and* its own output?

Comment: See my update - the issue is with the reference to `items` in the lambda that is not resolved until the query executes.

Answer (score 5):

After studying the two answers given and poking around a bit, I came up with a little program that better illustrates the problem.

```
    private int GetFirst(IEnumerable<int> items, int foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetFirst {0}", foo);
        var rslt = items.First(i => i == foo);
        Console.WriteLine("GetFirst returns {0}", rslt);
        return rslt;
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> GoNuts(IEnumerable<int> items)
    {
        items = items.Select(item =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Select item = {0}", item);
            return GetFirst(items, item);
        });
        return items;
    }
```

If you call that with:

```
var newList = GoNuts(new[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
```

You'll get this output repeatedly until you finally get `StackOverflowException`.

```
Select item = 1
GetFirst 1
Select item = 1
GetFirst 1
Select item = 1
GetFirst 1
...
```

What this shows is exactly what dasblinkenlight made clear in his updated answer: the query goes into an infinite loop trying to get the first item.

Let's write `GoNuts` a slightly different way:

```
    private IEnumerable<int> GoNuts(IEnumerable<int> items)
    {
        var originalItems = items;
        items = items.Select(item =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Select item = {0}", item);
            return GetFirst(originalItems, item);
        });
        return items;
    }
```

If you run that, it succeeds. Why? Because in this case it's clear that the call to `GetFirst` is passing a reference to the original items that were passed to the method. In the first case, `GetFirst` is passing a reference to the *new* `items` collection, which hasn't yet been realized. In turn, `GetFirst` says, "Hey, I need to enumerate this collection." And thus begins the first recursive call that eventually leads to `StackOverflowException`.

Interestingly, I was right *and* wrong when I said that it was consuming its own output. The `Select` is consuming the original input, as I would expect. The `First` is trying to consume the output.

Lots of lessons to be learned here. To me, the most important is "don't modify the value of input parameters."

Thanks to dasblinkenlight, D Stanley, and Lucas Trzesniewski for their help.