# C# Linq - How to understand this lazy evaluation behavior of Select?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a newbee for C# and encountereed an interesting Linq behavior as below.

`FlipNumber` has the expected behavior, select by index `Select((_, i) ...)` shown the correct behavior to flip the number string `n.Length - 1` times, while `FlipNumber1` only evaluated once as it select by item and with `Last()` to obtain the last iteration result.

Can anyone help to explain it?

Simple test with the following code (forget the efficiency plz)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static string FlipNumber(string n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"FlipNumber");
        return Enumerable.Range(0, n.Length - 1).Select((_, i) => {
            n = new string(n.Take(i).Concat(n.Skip(i).Reverse()).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} : {n}");
            return n;
        }).Last();
    }
    
    public static string FlipNumber1(string n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"FlipNumber1");
        return Enumerable.Range(0, n.Length - 1).Select(i => {
            n = new string(n.Take(i).Concat(n.Skip(i).Reverse()).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} : {n}");
            return n;
        }).Last();
    }

    // suggested by @DiplomacyNotWar
    // add `ToList()` before `Last()` makes the result same with FlipNumber
    public static string FlipNumber11(string n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"FlipNumber11");
        return Enumerable.Range(0, n.Length - 1).Select(i => {
            n = new string(n.Take(i).Concat(n.Skip(i).Reverse()).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} : {n}");
            return n;
        }).ToList().Last();
    }
    
    public static string FlipNumber2(string n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"FlipNumber2");
        return n.Select(i => {
            n = new string(n.Take(i).Concat(n.Skip(i).Reverse()).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} : {n}");
            return n;
        }).Last();
    }
  
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FlipNumber("123456789");
        FlipNumber1("123456789");
        FlipNumber11("123456789");
        FlipNumber2("123456789");
    }
}

/*
Results:

FlipNumber
0 : 987654321
1 : 912345678
2 : 918765432
3 : 918234567
4 : 918276543
5 : 918273456
6 : 918273654
7 : 918273645
FlipNumber1
7 : 123456798
FlipNumber11
0 : 987654321
1 : 912345678
2 : 918765432
3 : 918234567
4 : 918276543
5 : 918273456
6 : 918273654
7 : 918273645
FlipNumber2
1 : 123456789
2 : 123456789
3 : 123456789
4 : 123456789
5 : 123456789
6 : 123456789
7 : 123456789
8 : 123456789
9 : 123456789
*/
```

Comment: What is the goal of this code?

Comment: Does it matter? Im just curious about the different behaviors for the codes i tried. Anyway, this code aims to flip number string for fun. Thanks.

Comment: I believe @DiplomacyNotWar was asking "what did you expect to see?". Is one of the 2 functions behaving as you expect? Maybe it's me and maybe it's because im tryind to decipherit on a phone, but I find your code very hard to follow. You are changing `n` while your `Enumerable.Range(0  n.Length)` is executing. I have no idea what happens then

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks. I edited the description and hope it is clearer now. I just wonder why `Select` only executed once in `FlipNumber1`.

Comment: I learned some time back that reassigning an argument can lead to some really non-obvious behavior. Here the argument to the function is `n`, and then you're reassigning a value to it. I suspect that if you change `n = new string...` to `s = new string...`, and of course return `s`, that you'll see the behavior you expect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993443/why-does-this-method-result-in-an-infinite-loop for what I think is a similar problem.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks. Yes, but i think in C#, `n` is just a reference, assigned it a `new string` only changed what it refers to but not itself. That's why i tried `FlipNumber2`. What really interests me is the behavior of `Select` in `FlipNumber1`. And I do think it has some relationship with the `defer` evaluation of the Linq. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not following. `Select` isn't a normal function; it's an iterator block (i.e., it has a `yield return` statement). In my head, it executes just once (even though it is entered many times)

Comment: Yes, `n` is a variable of reference type, and it initially refers to an immutable string. But you reassign it. I'm pretty sure that `Enumerable.Range` is also an interator block (with a yield return). I have no idea what happens when you reassign `n` whe it's the variable that is used to terminate the iteration

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, `Select` is used to iterated the former `Enumerable.Range()`, but compared with `Select` in `FlipNumber`, i only changed to iterate the item instead of index, then its havior changed. That's why i feel it stopped eariler than expected. Thank.

Comment: I've tried to look in to the generated `IL` and `JITasm` code, but i did not see any significant difference between `FlipNumber` and `FlipNumber1` :< .

Comment: It matters because how can we understand what it's doing wrong if you don't tell us what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Hi buddy, take easy... I may make a mistake in asking manner, sorry for that.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes, and i've revised the desciption and try to make my point clearly.  
 Just inform me if it still not clear enough to you. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to reassigning a value to `n`, but rather using `.Last()`. If you change it to `.ToList().Last()` then you get the same result as `FlipNumber`. It seems like some optimization is occuring here.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes and i think it's about the defer evaluation behavior. I wonder whether there's a way to see its real execution pattern. Thanks.

Comment: I think all bets are off when you have `n.Select(...` and `n = ...`. There may be some incredibly cool algorithm going on here or it's just a mind-bending frig around. My suggestion is that the OP remove the `n =...` and ask a simple question about enumerable laziness.

Comment: With Linq commands (which have loads of overloads), it is always hard to work out what code you are actually running.  If you look at the type of object that `.Last()` is operating on, you will see that FlipNumber1 is the only one where the type is `System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectRangeIterator``1[System.String]` and looking in ILSpy at the code, it appears Last will call TryGetLast which in this case will go straight to the last result. I presume the others are using the `System.Linq.Enumerable.Last` which in these cases goes through all the results until it reaches the end.

Comment: There is only supposed to be one back-tick in that answer above, but if I just use one, it removes it and terminates the formatting, so I have added a second.

Comment: Of course, the question is now why does the  Enumerable.Range in FlipNumber1 produce a different type from the other methods?

Comment: @sgmoore Yes, i noticed the diff in IL code and wonder why and when this happens. Im a newbee for C# and would like to know how to investigate those internal behavior of its Linq facilities. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks. I just encountered this issue and wanna find its internal mechanism, that's why i asked this question here. It may or may not get dedicated answer and helpful discussion is enough.

Comment: @Harold - It's answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This boils down to a number of optimisations that are in LINQ. When we examine the source for `Last` we see it is this:

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    bool found;
    TSource result = source.TryGetLast(out found);
    if (!found)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException();
    }
    return result;
}
```

We follow that to `TryGetLast` and see it is this:

```
private static TSource TryGetLast<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, out bool found)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.source);
    }
    IPartition<TSource> partition = source as IPartition<TSource>;
    if (partition != null)
    {
        return partition.TryGetLast(out found);
    }
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            found = true;
            return list[count - 1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            TSource current;
            do
            {
                current = enumerator.Current;
            }
            while (enumerator.MoveNext());
            found = true;
            return current;
        }
    }
    found = false;
    return default(TSource);
}
```

And then finally the `IPartition<TSource>`:

```
internal interface IPartition<TElement> : IIListProvider<TElement>, IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable
{
    IPartition<TElement> Skip(int count);

    IPartition<TElement> Take(int count);

    TElement TryGetElementAt(int index, out bool found);

    TElement TryGetFirst(out bool found);

    TElement TryGetLast(out bool found);
}
```

The `Select(i =>` returns a `SelectIPartitionIterator` under the hood, which implements `IPartition<TElement>` so it is able to jump to the last element.

When you do `Select((_, i) =>` it's not creating a `IPartition<TSource>` so it is forced to do a full iteration.

The whole use of `n =` in this question was just a furphy and should have been avoided. It turns an excellent question into one that hides what's truly going on.