# Setting a Property via Reflection in a copied List updates original list

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, setvalue

I'm experiencing a problem in my C# code and I'm sure it has to do with the way I'm using reflection, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

To the best of my knowledge, if I have:

```
List1 = List<MyClass>
```

and use a syntax similar to

```
List2 = new List<MyClass>(List1);
```

Then `List2` should be a copy of `List1` and any updates made to it should not reflect in the original list.

That being the case, consider the following test code:

```
public class Fake
{
    public string MyVal { get; set; }
}

public List<Fake> List1;
public List<Fake> List2;

public void UpdateClassTest()
{
    List1 = new List<Fake>() {new Fake() { MyVal = "hello" } };

    List2 = new List<Fake>(List1);
    string propName;

    System.Type type = typeof(Fake);
    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        propName = pi.Name;
        List2.ForEach(f => pi.SetValue(f, "Good Bye"));
    }
}
```

When I run this **Both** `List1[0]` and `List2[0]` get updated to "Good Bye", but I would assume `List1` would not be affected by the changes I'm making to `List2`.

What am I doing wrong or not understanding here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new List(List other) does not do a deep copy.  When you modify the item at [0] it's modifying the original object, which exists in both lists.

[See this other question about implementing ICloneable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

Comment: Thanks!! - That sucks, but makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Copying the list means that the lists are different objects. The elements contained by the lists are still the same. For instance:

```
List1 = new List<Fake>() {new Fake { MyVal = "hello" } };
List2 = new List<Fake>(List1);

List2.Add(new Fake { MyVal = "hey" });
Console.WriteLine(List1.Length); // 1
Console.WriteLine(List2.Length); // 2

List2[0].MyVal = "hi";
Console.WriteLine(List1[0].MyVal) // hi
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That sucks, but makes sense!