# In C# How do I copy a list to another list in such a way that on modifying the copied list the original list is not modified

Tags: c#, list, copy

I am trying to copy a list to another list using AddRange or other ways but nothing seems to work correctly. No matter whatever way I try if, I modify the copied list it modifies the original list too. The only way it work if I copy using foreach loop.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new List<Employee>{ new Employee { ID = "101", Name ="ABC1"}, new Employee{ID = "102", Name = "ABC2"}, new Employee{ ID = "103", Name = "ABC3"}};

        var tets2 = new List<Employee>(test);

        tets2[0].ID = "1-73";
        TestMethod(test.ToList());
    }

    private static void TestMethod(List<Employee> test)
    {
        var test1 = new List<Employee>(test);

        test1.AddRange(test);

        //This is the only one that work
        foreach(var item in test)
        {
            var x = new Employee { ID = item.ID, Name = item.Name };
            test1.Add(x);
        }

        test1[0].ID = "104";
    }
```

Is there no shorter way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

Comment: You could use LINQ for this I believe:

`originalList.ForEach(x => CopiedList.Add(new CopiedListObject { prop = x.prop, prop2 = x.prop2 })`

Answer (score 3):

It's not modifying the list - it's modifying the item in the list.
You can have two or more lists - each is a `List<Employee>` - and if you copy the items to another list or array, the items in both lists are the same items.

```
var x = new Employee { ID = "xyz", Name = "Bob" };
var list = new List<Employee>();
list.Add(x);
var array = new Employee[]{x};
var y = x;
y.ID = "abc";
```

In this example there is one and only one instance of `Employee`, but four *references* to that one `Employee`.

- `x` is one reference
- `list[0]` is another
- `array[0]`
- `y`

However you refer to that one instance, including `list[0].ID = "new id"` it's all the same instance of `Employee`.

To create a copy you could do something like this - this is a verbose example, not necessarily the way you'd want to actually implement it:

```
var newList = new List<Employee>();
foreach(var employee in sourceList) //the list you want to copy from
{
    newList.Add(new Employee{ID=employee.ID, Name=employee.Name});
}
```

The items added to `newList` aren't the same objects in `sourceList`. They are new objects with the same properties.

If you foresee the need to do this frequently then you could make `Employee` implement `ICloneable`.

```
public class Employee : ICloneable
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public object Clone()
    {
        return new Employee{ID=ID, Name=Name};
    }
}
```

Or, because the properties are just value types, you could just do this, which copies properties from the source object into a new object.

```
public class Employee : ICloneable
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Then to create a new list you could create an extension method:

```
public static class EmployeeExtensions
{
    public static List<Employee> ToClonedList(this IEnumerable<Employee> source)
    {
        return source.Select(employee => employee.Clone() as Employee).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can create a cloned list from any `IEnumerable` set of employees like this:

```
var myClonedList = oldList.ToClonedList();
```

(To split hairs, you don't have to implement `ICloneable`. You could just write a method that copies the object. `ICloneable` is just a convention that lets others know they can call `.Clone()` and create a cloned object.)