# List changes when I assign it to a variable c#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, variables

I came across a problem. I am trying to make a tic tac toe game where you can play against an ai. But it does not really care in this problem. The board is a 2D list witch looks like this:

> [0, 1, 0]
>  [1, 2, 0]
>  [0, 2, 0]
>
> 0 is an empty spot
>  1 is player one (circle)
>  2 is player two (cross)

But I have a problem I need to iterate thru all the spots so I made this for loop.

```
List<List<int>> boardTry;
List<List<int>> board = new List<List<int>> { new List<int> { 0, 0, 0 }, new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, }, new List<int> { 0, 0, 0 } };

for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < 3; rowNum ++)
            {
                for (int colNum = 0; colNum < 3; colNum++)
                {
                    // Check if spot is empty
                    if (board[rowNum][colNum] == 0)
                    {
                        boardTry = board;
                        showBoard(board);

                        boardTry[rowNum][colNum] = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I created a method called showBoard to see how the list looked like.

```
void showBoard(List<List<int>> board)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (List<int> row in board)
            {
                sb.Append("[");
                foreach(int col in row)
                {
                    sb.Append(col.ToString() + " ");
                }
                sb.Append("]");
            }

            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(0, 8) + "\n" + sb.ToString(8, 8) + "\n" + sb.ToString(16, 8));

        }
```

But the problem is when I run this code is that the `board` list is changing with the `boardTry`. So each time I assign `boardTry` to `board`, `board` is getting equal to `boardTry`.

This is what I see when I run this code.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
boardTry = board;
```

It doesn't create a new list. `boardTry` and `board` are now both variables referring to the same list. So any changes made to `boardTry` are also made to `board`.

[Here's a very recent question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018001/in-c-sharp-how-do-i-copy-a-list-to-another-list-in-such-a-way-that-on-modifying/38018810#38018810) that discuss pretty much the same question and how to work around it. The short version is that you don't want to just assign the existing list to a new variable. You want to create a new list which is a copy of the existing list.

Here's an example of a function that copies an existing board into a new one. This is a little verbose:

```
List<List<int>> CopyBoard(List<List<int>> original)
{
    var copied = new List<List<int>>();
    foreach (var innerList in original)
    {
        copied.Add(new List<int>(innerList));
    }
    return copied;
}
```

Here's the same thing as a LINQ expression. We do this because if we take the original function and cram into one line that's slightly harder to read then we feel good about ourselves.

```
List<List<int>> CopyBoard(List<List<int>> original)
{
    return new List<List<int>>(original.Select(innerList=> innerList.ToList()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the really good explanation! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tic tac toe control (you can modify it):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TicTacToe : Panel
{
    public TicTacToe()
    {
        // You can change these properties.
        this.Size = new Size(281, 360);
        this.BackColor = Color.White;

        // Add the labels.
        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { wins, losses, turn });

        // To generate random numbers for the A.I
        Random opponentPlay = new Random();

        // A.I turn
        opponentDelay.Tick += delegate
        {
            opponentDelay.Interval = 20;
            Point opponentPos = new Point(opponentPlay.Next(0, 3), opponentPlay.Next(0, 3));
            if (board[opponentPos.X][opponentPos.Y].Text.Length == 0)
            {
                board[opponentPos.X][opponentPos.Y].Text = "X";
                opponentDelay.Interval = 500;
                opponentDelay.Stop();
                UpdateGame();
            }
        };

        // Setup board.
        for (int x = 0; x < board.Count; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < board.Count; y++)
            {
                board[x][y].Location = new Point(4 + (x * 92), 4 + (y * 92));
                // Add player turn event.
                board[x][y].Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (turn.Name == "1")
                    {
                        if (((Button)sender).Text.Length == 0)
                        {
                            ((Button)sender).Text = "0";
                            UpdateGame();
                        }
                    }
                };

                this.Controls.Add(board[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Check game for wins, losses, and draws.
    public void UpdateGame()
    {   
        // Check if player won.
        if (board[0][0].Text == "0" && board[1][0].Text == "0" && board[2][0].Text == "0")
            EndGame(0);
        else if (board[0][1].Text == "0" && board[1][1].Text == "0" && board[2][1].Text == "0")
            EndGame(0);
        else if (board[0][2].Text == "0" && board[1][2].Text == "0" && board[2][2].Text == "0")
            EndGame(0);
        else if (board[0][0].Text == "0" && board[0][1].Text == "0" && board[0][2].Text == "0")
            EndGame(0);
        else if (board[1][0].Text == "0" && board[1][1].Text == "0" && board[1][2].Text == "0")
            EndGame(0);
        else if (board[2][0].Text == "0" && board[2][1].Text == "0" && board[2][2].Text == "0")
            EndGame(0);
        else if (board[0][0].Text == "0" && board[1][1].Text == "0" && board[2][2].Text == "0")
            EndGame(0);
        else if (board[0][2].Text == "0" && board[1][1].Text == "0" && board[2][0].Text == "0")
            EndGame(0);

        // Check if opponent won.
        if (board[0][0].Text == "X" && board[1][0].Text == "X" && board[2][0].Text == "X")
            EndGame(1);
        else if (board[0][1].Text == "X" && board[1][1].Text == "X" && board[2][1].Text == "X")
            EndGame(1);
        else if (board[0][2].Text == "X" && board[1][2].Text == "X" && board[2][2].Text == "X")
            EndGame(1);
        else if (board[0][0].Text == "X" && board[0][1].Text == "X" && board[0][2].Text == "X")
            EndGame(1);
        else if (board[1][0].Text == "X" && board[1][1].Text == "X" && board[1][2].Text == "X")
            EndGame(1);
        else if (board[2][0].Text == "X" && board[2][1].Text == "X" && board[2][2].Text == "X")
            EndGame(1);
        else if (board[0][0].Text == "X" && board[1][1].Text == "X" && board[2][2].Text == "X")
            EndGame(1);
        else if (board[0][2].Text == "X" && board[1][1].Text == "X" && board[2][0].Text == "X")
            EndGame(1);

        // Check if nobody won.
        if (board[0][0].Text != "" && board[0][1].Text != "" && board[0][2].Text != "" && board[1][0].Text != "" && board[1][1].Text != "" && board[1][2].Text != "" && board[2][0].Text != "" && board[2][1].Text != "" && board[2][2].Text != "")
            EndGame(2);

        // Change turn.
        if (turn.Name == "2")
        {
            turn.Name = "1";
            turn.Text = "Your turn";
        }
        else
        {
            turn.Name = "2";
            turn.Text = "Opponents turn";
            opponentDelay.Start();
        }
    }

    // End game (or end round).
    public void EndGame(int win)
    {   
        if (win == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Win!", "Tic Tac Toe");
            wins.Name = (Convert.ToInt32(wins.Name) + 1).ToString();
            wins.Text = "Wins: " + wins.Name;
        }
        else if (win == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry but you lost, better luck next time...", "Tic Tac Toe");
            losses.Name = (Convert.ToInt32(losses.Name) + 1).ToString();
            losses.Text = "Losses: " + losses.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Draw! No one won...", "Tic Tac Toe");
        }

        // Reset board.
        for (int x = 0; x < board.Count; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < board.Count; y++)
            {
                board[x][y].Text = "";
            }
        }

        // Set the turn.
        turn.Name = "2";
    }

    // Variables
    public Label wins = new Label() { Text = "Wins: 0", Name = "0", Location = new Point(30, 310), AutoSize = false, Size = new Size(54, 17)  };
    public Label losses = new Label() { Text = "Losses: 0", Name = "0", Location = new Point(95, 310), AutoSize = false, Size = new Size(66, 17)  };
    public Label turn = new Label() { Text = "Your turn", Name = "1", Location = new Point(175, 310) };
    public Timer opponentDelay = new Timer() { Interval = 500 };

    // Instead of buttons and int lists, where you have to add click event and get button index to change int list and button text, just use a button list and click evnt which read the button text and changes it.
    public List<List<Button>> board = new List<List<Button>>
    {
        new List<Button>
        {
            new Button() { Text = "", Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 26f, FontStyle.Bold), UseVisualStyleBackColor = true, TabStop = false, Size = new Size(90, 90) },
            new Button() { Text = "", Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 26f, FontStyle.Bold), UseVisualStyleBackColor = true, TabStop = false, Size = new Size(90, 90) },
            new Button() { Text = "", Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 26f, FontStyle.Bold), UseVisualStyleBackColor = true, TabStop = false, Size = new Size(90, 90) }
        },
        new List<Button>
        {
            new Button() { Text = "", Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 26f, FontStyle.Bold), UseVisualStyleBackColor = true, TabStop = false, Size = new Size(90, 90) },
            new Button() { Text = "", Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 26f, FontStyle.Bold), UseVisualStyleBackColor = true, TabStop = false, Size = new Size(90, 90) },
            new Button() { Text = "", Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 26f, FontStyle.Bold), UseVisualStyleBackColor = true, TabStop = false, Size = new Size(90, 90) }
        },
        new List<Button>
        {
            new Button() { Text = "", Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 26f, FontStyle.Bold), UseVisualStyleBackColor = true, TabStop = false, Size = new Size(90, 90) },
            new Button() { Text = "", Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 26f, FontStyle.Bold), UseVisualStyleBackColor = true, TabStop = false, Size = new Size(90, 90) },
            new Button() { Text = "", Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 26f, FontStyle.Bold), UseVisualStyleBackColor = true, TabStop = false, Size = new Size(90, 90) }
        }
    };
}
```

**Usage:**

```
TicTacToe TicTacToeGame = new TicTacToe();
...Controls.Add(TicTacToeGame);
```

**What it looks like:**

[image]