# Generating a new instance of a List in C#

Tags: c#, list, reference, clone

I have a problem with using C#, if I initialize a certain list, lets say `List<T> exampleList` using another pre-existing list, lets say **toModify** like this: `List<T> exampleList = new List<T>(toModify)`. When I later modify **toModify** list the newly created list also modifies itself. If it passes the value by reference shouldn't the value of **exampleList** stay the same since it was generated from the other one?

TLDR: Value of a list I initialize using another list(second list) changes when I change the second list. I come from a Java background and can't understand why this happens. Will I always have to use clone?

Comment: C#'s behavior is exactly the same as Java's behavior in this regard. Can you explain what you mean when you say you "modify" the list? Perhaps provide a minimal code example to show the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us use this example :

```
        List<A> firstList = new List<A>()
        {
            new A() { Id = 3 },
            new A() { Id = 5 }
        };

        List<A> secondList = new List<A>(firstList);

        secondList[1].Id = 999;

        Console.WriteLine(firstList[1].Id);
```

Output : 999

The main reason for this is that even though we created a new `List<T>` that points to a new memory allocated on heap it still works with references the point to same objects.

To create a list that points to new (!) objects with the same values we'd need to clone these elements somehow, one way to do it is to use LINQ `.Select()` method in order to create new objects and then a `ToList()` method to copy the list itself:

```
        List<A> firstList = new List<A>()
        {
            new A() { Id = 3 },
            new A() { Id = 5 }
        };

        List<A> secondList = firstList.Select(el => new A() { Id = el.Id }).ToList();

        secondList[1].Id = 999;

        Console.WriteLine(firstList[1].Id);
```

Output : 5

Comment: How can I make the object copy the reference to another memory block and just modify that block?

Comment: Hmmmm, what do you mean by this line : 'object copy reference to another memory block'  ?

Comment: Instead of just making the new object point or refer to the first one, how can I like create an exact copy of that reference and put it in another place so that when I modify the second object it doesn't modify the first?

Comment: Well, you can read something about reference types and how they work in C#. Reference just points to the object, let's call it A and when you want to create another object B with same values but so that is not modified when A is, you need to create a new object and a new reference to it.

Comment: As you can see objects in C# behave like objects in real life, if you modify object and it is referenced in some 3 lists - it'll be modified for all of them because these lists merely hold a reference to it, not the object itself.

Comment: you can use reflection to create the same object instance 
List<A> secondList = firstList.Select(el => (A)Activator.CreateInstance(el.GetType()).ToList();

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

You're creating a new list containing the same items as the old list. If you clear the first list, the items in the second stay.

But if you change a property for one of the items in the first list, then it is the same object in the second list.

So, both list are referencing the same items in memory. When you write `list1[0].SomeProperty = 1` you're changing that using object reference that is the same in `list2`, so changes are reflected in the second list.

For how to clone a List and generate new references for items, check this SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222640/3185569).

Comment: Why why dont they make a function for the interface List so that you can copy it without that happening? In other words change the memory reference creating a new one without having to create a clone method to do the job?

Comment: @TiPiTo Copying an object is more complex that you imagine. You may have a hierarchy of sub objects and complex properties. Google "Deep Copy" in C#.

Comment: Wouldn't using a deep copy be a very inefficient way to "clone" the object, since it goes through every index instead of just copying the memory block?

Comment: @TiPiTo Yes, which is why it's a red flag to see it being done; typically you'd design the code in such a way that it's not necessary.

Comment: Now that you mention that, what can I do in order to prevent having to deal with this? Is there a pattern or something else that is usually implemented in cases where this problem is expected?

Answer (score 2):

In the following line:

```
List<T> exampleList = new List<T>(toModify)
```

you create a list of T calling `List<T>`'s constructor that takes one argument of type `IEnumerable<T>`. For further info on the latter, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Method's arguments in C#  are passed *by default* by value and not by reference. They can be passed by reference, but you have to explicitly state this in the signature of the corresponding method using the `ref` keyword and at the point you call this method, using again the same keyword. So the `toModify` is passed by value to the constructor of `List<T>`.

What's the importance of this?

In C# types can be divided into two categories (despite the fact that all types inherit from the System.Object):

- Value types
- Reference types

When we pass a value type as an argument, we pass a copy of it's value. Each modification we make in either the original value or in the copy of the original value is not reflected to one another. On the other hand, when we pass a reference type as an argument, we pass a copy of that reference. So now we have two references (pointers) that point to the same location in memory. That being said, it's clear that if we change any property of the object in which both references points to, this would be visible by both of them.

In your case, this is what is happening. `toModify` is a list of reference types (under the hood you have an array, whose items are references to other objects). So any change to the items of the initial list, `toModify`, is reflected to the list you construct based on this list.

A simple example that you could use to verify the above is the following:

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"X: {X}, Y: {Y}";
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listA = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
        var listB = new List<int>(listA);
        // Before the modification
        Console.WriteLine(listA[0]); // prints 1
        Console.WriteLine(listB[0]); // prints 1
        listA[0] = 2;
        // After the mofication
        Console.WriteLine(listA[0]); // prints 2
        Console.WriteLine(listB[0]); // prints 1
        Console.ReadKey();

        var pointsA = new List<Point>
        {
            new Point {X = 3, Y = 4},
            new Point {X = 4, Y = 5},
            new Point {X = 6, Y = 8},
        };
        var pointsB = new List<Point>(pointsA);
        // Before the modification
        Console.WriteLine(pointsA[0]); // prints X: 3, Y: 4
        Console.WriteLine(pointsB[0]); // prints X: 3, Y: 4
        pointsA[0].X = 4; 
        pointsA[0].Y = 3;
        // After the modification
        Console.WriteLine(pointsA[0]); // prints X: 4, Y: 3
        Console.WriteLine(pointsB[0]); // prints X: 4, Y: 3

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make a reference type pass by value without using the clone method?