# create exact duplicate of a list of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I create an exact duplicate of a list in c#?

```
List<string> addedAttachments = new List<string>();
addedAttachments = (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserFeedbackImage"];

List<string> tempList = addedAttachments;
```

Stores tempList in a different order

Thanks

Comment: This simply creates a new reference to the original list, not a new list.

Comment: That is not true; that is exactly the same list (not even a copy).

Answer (score 3):

You only assign the reference of your first list `addadAttachments` to a new variable, but don't create a new list.

To create a new list simply call

```
List<string> tempList = new List<string>(addedAttachments);
```

The order of the strings in the lists stays the same.

---

But note that this is only appropriate for immutable types like `string`. With a list of complex mutable objects, you would add the *same* objects to the new list, so if you change properties of an object in the old list, the "object in the new list" is also changed (it *is* the changed object). So you might also need to copy the objects.

Answer (score 1):

To create a *copy*, try *Linq*:

```
List<string> tempList = addedAttachments.ToList();
```

Comment: Just for completeness: the `ToList()` extension does nothing else but `return new List<T>(source);`, since `List<T>` has a constructor `public List<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `List<string>` and string is immutable you can do:

```
List<string> tempList = addedAttachments.ToList();
```

If you have a custom object in your list then you should look for [cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c).