# c# collections and re-numbering not working as expected

Tags: c#

Hi i'm trying to setup simple test data.

I simply want to take a collection which is smallish and make it bigger by add itself multiple times.

After I;ve added them together i want to re-number the property LineNumber
so that there are no duplicates and that it goes in order. 1,2,3,4....

no matter what i try it doesn't seem to work and i cant see the mistake.

```
var sampleTemplateLine = dataContext.TemplateFileLines.ToList();


*//tired this doesnt work either*           
//List<TemplateFileLine> lineRange = new List<TemplateFileLine>();
//lineRange.AddRange(sampleTemplateLine);
//lineRange.AddRange(sampleTemplateLine);
//lineRange.AddRange(sampleTemplateLine);
//lineRange.AddRange(sampleTemplateLine);

var allProducts = sampleTemplateLine
                       .Concat(sampleTemplateLine)
                       .Concat(sampleTemplateLine)
                       .Concat(sampleTemplateLine)
                       .ToList();
int i = 1;
foreach (var item in allProducts)
{
     item.LineNumber = i;
     i++;
}
```

*this doesnt seem to work either*

```
  //re-number the line number
  var total = allProducts.Count();
  for (int i =0; i < total; i++)
  {
      allProducts[i].LineNumber = i+1;
  }
```

**PROBLEM: below RETURN 4 when i'm expecting 1**

```
var itemthing = allProducts.Where(x => x.LineNumber == 17312).ToList();
```

Comment: In short - the problem is when you add the same list 4 times, you have 4 references to the same object in the new list. When you edit one of them - you edit all (4) of them.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding the same objects multiple times. You wold have to add new objects or clone the ones you have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is they are pointing the same object. So if you change a property it changes all the pointed objects at the same

You can use `Clone` method if it exist, if not you can create your own Clone method like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c).

Comment: The OPs code already contains `AddRange` calls (commented out) and it suffers exactly the same problem as the `Concat`s do.

Comment: thanks, but i already tired loads including this... Bojan pointed me in the right direction, but seems like quite a mission to clone.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah, I didn't notice, thanks.