# How to save value of field in class

Tags: c#

I have an problem to make class as value type. This is my example:

```
class exampleClass
{
    private List<string> temp = new List<string>();

    public exampleClass(List<string> list)
    {
        temp = list;
    }

    public List<string> list { get { return temp; } }
}
```

... and initialize window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    List<string> exampleList = new List<string>();
    exampleList.Add("TEST");
    Klasy.exampleClass test = new Klasy.exampleClass(exampleList);
    exampleList.Clear();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

My question is: **How to save value of list in exmapleClass when I clear exampleList. What I should change in class to make it independent of the exampleList?**

Thanks

Comment: Copy all the elements not the list reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

Comment: The least you could do when downvoting, is explaining why. He won't be able to figure it out, he is new to the site. Also OP, you should take the [StackOverflow's Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take a look at the [ask] page before posting new questions, in order to understand how the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the list reference, instead of that creates a new **list instance** and pass it to `exampleClass` so that even when exampleList is clear, it would not impact the exampleClass.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        List<string> exampleList = new List<string>();
        exampleList.Add("TEST");
        Klasy.exampleClass test = new Klasy.exampleClass(new List<string>(exampleList));
        exampleList.Clear();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: It should not be the responsibility of the user of this class to guarantee that it works as desired. The class itself is responsible by creating a new list instance in the constructor. Otherwise 9 of 10 people will use this class in a wrong way.