# How to create multiple lists from one list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I am doing a research paper over the multiple sorting methods in C#.
To do this I need to create a list for sorting, then sort this list using the sort methods. The problem is i don't know an easy way to make a copy of this list without creating around 100 unique lists so i can effectively test each method.

-Is there an easy way to create multiple copies of a list in a efficient way.

-Is there a way to clear a list then re-populate it with the original list 
 eliminating the need to create a lot of unique lists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var list2 = list1.ToList()` ?

Comment: one tip i have : allocate enough space for the list by specifying a capacity in its constructor. This way the list does not need to reallocate the list while adding items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample list:

```
var list1 = new List<string>();
```

> -Is there an easy way to create multiple copies of a list in a efficient way.

```
var list2 = list1.ToList();
```

> -Is there a way to clear a list then re-populate it with the original list eliminating the need to create a lot of unique lists.

```
var list2 = new List<string>(list1);
list2.Clear();
list2.AddRange(list1);
list2.Clear();
list2.AddRange(list1);
```

** Note that using `.Clear` the [Capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the list isn't reset. Since we're just reusing the same source list without changing the size, I don't think this is a problem for you. *If* you were changing the number of test items between tests, I would initialize the list with a capacity to match the size of the *largest* list in your test set.

Comment: Thanks i ended up figuring it out immediately after posting it i should've invested more time into trial and error thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy list to another as shown below

```
List<string> source = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
List<string> target;

// simplest all source ellements from list constructor
target = new List<string>(source);
```

Another way using loop

```
// loop with condition
target = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in source)
{
   target.Add(item);                
}
```