# How can I prevent StackOverflowException in my code

Tags: c#, recursion

In my code, I cannot figure out why I keep getting 'Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.' only on the second output.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace _2018JuniorQ5
{
    class Program
    {
        //Variable Decleration
        public static int pages = 0;
        public static string[] bookFormat;
        public static List<string> alreadyChecked = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> nodesToCheck = new List<string>();
        public static int level = 0;
        public static List<string> childrenNodes = new List<string>();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get input
            pages = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            bookFormat = new string[pages];
            for (int x=0; x<pages; x++)
            {
                bookFormat[x] = Console.ReadLine();
            }        
            //Display if all pages are reachable
            Console.WriteLine(getReachablePages(1));
            //Find shortest path
            List<string> NodeBegin = new List<string>();
            NodeBegin.Add("1");
            Console.WriteLine(getShortestPath(NodeBegin));            
        }
        public static string getReachablePages(int pageToCheck)
        {
            string[] options=(bookFormat[pageToCheck - 1]).Split(' ');
            alreadyChecked.Add(Convert.ToString(pageToCheck));
            for (int a=1; a<=Convert.ToInt32(options[0]); a++)
            {
                if (!alreadyChecked.Contains(options[a]))
                {
                    getReachablePages(Convert.ToInt32(options[a]));
                }       
            }
            if (alreadyChecked.Count == pages)
            {
                return "Y";               
            }
            else
            {
                return "N";
            }
            alreadyChecked.Clear();  
        }
        public static int getShortestPath(List<string> nodesToCheck)
        {
            level++;
            childrenNodes.Clear();
            for (int q = 0; q < nodesToCheck.Count; q++)
            {
                string[] options = bookFormat[Convert.ToInt32(nodesToCheck[q])-1].Split(' ');                
                if (options[0] == "0")
                {
                    return level;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int t = 1; t < options.Length; t++)
                    {
                        if (!alreadyChecked.Contains(options[t]))
                        {
                            childrenNodes.Add(options[t]);
                            alreadyChecked.Add(nodesToCheck[q]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                nodesToCheck.Clear();
            }
            return getShortestPath(childrenNodes);
        }
    }
}
```

The first output from the getReachablePages method works, and does not give any errors. However, the second output from the getShortestPath gives the "Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException" error. Can someone explain why the getReachablePages method works, but the getShortestPath method doesn't work?

Comment: Your recursion is too deep, either because its just too deep or endless / mistake. Use an iteration or a stack class, or fix the mistake. Please make sure you have fully debugged your code

Comment: Your recursion is being caused by `childrenNodes` being empty. _Empty you say?_ Yes. Empty. When you call `getShortestPath(childrenNodes);`, you pass `childrenNodes` as a reference, meaning that `nodesToCheck` and `childrenNodes` are the same, so when you call `childrenNodes.Clear();`, you are also clearing `nodesToCheck`. Because there's nothing in the list, there's no exit condition, so you recurse forever. I'm sure you'd find this by stepping through with the [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: Can you explain why nodesToCheck and childrenNodes are the same? Aren't they two different variables? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: [This should demonstrate it](https://rextester.com/XUUX99496). See the link in my answer for detailed information about  reference vs value types.

Comment: I'm guessing `alreadyChecked.Clear()` happens a lot in `getReachablePages`. I'm guessing mostly `"N"` from that one?

Comment: John, I've seen your demonstration. What can I do to make each independent and prevent the issue?

Comment: @Cube ...huh? Doesn't my answer already answer that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem at the moment is that `List<string>` is a [reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c), so when you pass `childrenNodes` to `getShortestPath` (`getShortestPath(childrenNodes)`), you're actually passing a reference to the same list in memory.

The next thing you do is call `childrenNodes.Clear()`, which empties that list. Because `nodesToCheck` and `childrenNodes` are both pointing at the same list, calling `childrenNodes.Clear()` means that you have no nodes to check.

Why does this cause a `StackOverflowException`? It causes one because you have no exit condition for when `nodesToCheck` is empty. You just keep calling the same method over and over.

I propose the following solution:

```
public static int getShortestPath(List<string> nodesToCheck)
{
    if (!nodesToCheck.Any())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    var childrenNodes = new List<string>();
    level++;
    for (int q = 0; q < nodesToCheck.Count; q++)
    {
        string[] options = bookFormat[Convert.ToInt32(nodesToCheck[q])-1].Split(' ');                
        if (options[0] == "0")
        {
            return level;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int t = 1; t < options.Length; t++)
            {
                if (!alreadyChecked.Contains(options[t]))
                {
                    childrenNodes.Add(options[t]);
                    alreadyChecked.Add(nodesToCheck[q]);
                }
            }
        }
        nodesToCheck.Clear();
    }
    return getShortestPath(childrenNodes);
}
```

- When `nodesToCheck` is empty, return `-1` (i.e. no path).
- Create a new `List<string>` for `childrenNodes` within the `getShortestPath` method.

While this should fix your problem, I would recommend making your entire method self-contained. It's essentially a stateless method, but you're maintaining state outside the method, which led to the problem you have seen, and could lead to more problems if you call this method in a multi-threaded environment.

The other odd thing I noticed, is that you're looping through `nodesToCheck`, but the way your code is written means that you will only ever consider the first node because you clear `nodesToCheck` at the end of the first iteration, leaving the list empty. Further more, you're adding `nodesToCheck[q]` to `alreadChecked` once per item in `options`, which I'm sure can't be right.

I recommend learning to use [the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio. The debugger allows you to step through your code line-by-line, inspect variables, etc. - this will help you locate problems in your code.

P.S. While it is not the correct solution to your problem, if you wish to copy a list you can use [LINQ's `ToList()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396131/3181933) method: `var listB = listA.ToList();`