# All lists deleted

Tags: c#, list

I want to clear *just* `birkatmankontur` list but this  code *clears all* lists in my program

```
katmankonturlari.Add(ii, birkatmankontur);

katmankonturlari.ToList();
birkatmankontur.Clear();
```

Comment: `katmankonturlari.ToList();` returns a new `List<T>` which you *discard*. You may want `katmankonturlari = katmankonturlari.ToList();` i.e. create a shallow copy of `katmankonturlari`

Comment: [Reference types vs value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c) and [how to clone a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c).

Comment: In your code snippet there is only _one_ list (`birkatmankontur`); what other lists are you talking about?

Comment: Depending on what types those lists are, you probably have just another reference to the exact same list. So modifying one is reflected in the other as well. However with that little information it´s hard to tell exactly.

Comment: List<Coordinate> birkontur = new List<Coordinate>() this is also my list and after my processes this is also clear

Comment: And what is `katmankonturlari`? Btw.: is `birkontur` and `birkatmankontur` the same list?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve]. We don't have enough information with just those three lines of code.

Comment: `katmankonturlari.Add(ii, birkatmankontur);` is this valid syntax?

Comment: @codeninja.sj Not really. Making me wonder how the answer solved OPs problem.

Comment: yes it is valid and solved my problem

Comment: @HimBromBeere: It is if `katmankonturlari` is a dictionary. The question is still very unclear though, and the OP doesn't appear to want to try to improve it.

Comment: Most likely he's adding the list `birkatmankontur` (shape/contour?) to a list of lists in `katmankonturlari`, (list of shapes/contours? layer strokes?) and then clear the list he added preparing for a new batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
// Create a shallow copy of birkatmankontur and add it into katmankonturlari
katmankonturlari.Add(ii, birkatmankontur.ToList());

// Clear original birkatmankontur; 
// note, that katmankonturlari contains birkatmankontur's copy  
birkatmankontur.Clear();
```